# Multiple GitHub Accounts & SSH Config

Tags: ssh, github, ssh-keys

I'm having some trouble getting two different SSH keys/GitHub accounts to play well together.  I have the following setup:

Repos accessible from one account using `git@github.com:accountname`

Repos accessible from another account using `git@github.com:anotheraccount`

Each account has its own SSH key.  Both SSH keys have been added and I have created a config file.  I don't believe the config file is correct though.  I'm not quite sure how to specify that repos accessed using `git@github.com:accountname` should use `id_rsa` and `git@github.com:anotheraccount` should use `id_rsa_anotheraccount`.

Comment: I found this link helpful https://medium.freecodecamp.org/manage-multiple-github-accounts-the-ssh-way-2dadc30ccaca

Comment: I have 3 separate SSH identities in ~/.ssh/config. The one for school server has a passcode; the 2 for separate work/personal GitHub accts do not. Running `git pull` kept failing & asking for the school passcode, despite separate Identity files, "IdentitiesOnly=yes," separate domains & Hostnames, all present in `ssh-add -l` ... The uni key was 'first' regardless of that setup. Had to move its section below the others in .ssh/config, and now `git pull` from both GitHub accts succeeds w/o asking for uni ssh password.

Comment: That is answered in detail here https://superuser.com/questions/232373/how-to-tell-git-which-private-key-to-use

Comment: Check the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50746763/1814970) with the `sshCommand` git config option.

Answer (score 406, accepted):

Andy Lester's response is accurate but I found an important extra step I needed to make to get this to work. In trying to get two profiles set up, one for personal and one for work, my `~/.ssh/config` was roughly as follows:

```
Host me.github.com
    HostName github.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/me_rsa

Host work.github.com
    HostName github.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/work_rsa
```

My work profile didn't take until I did a `ssh-add ~/.ssh/work_rsa`. After that connections to github used the correct profile. Previously they defaulted to the first public key.

For **Could not open a connection to your authentication agent** when using `ssh-add`,
check:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17695338/1760313

Comment: By using ssh-add, I could see that I did not have the file permissions for the key set correctly. Once I fixed that everything worked. So thanks!

Comment: See also http://doblock.com/articles/using-public-keys-with-multiple-github-accounts.  The key new piece of info there is that you may need to add the username ("work", in this example) to the hostname in the remote URL, i.e., git@work.github.com:work/my_repo.git (as opposed to "git@github.com...")

Comment: This works: http://superuser.com/questions/232373/tell-git-which-private-key-to-use

Comment: To fix the problem that "they defaulted to the first public key", add `IdentitiesOnly yes` to the `Host *` section of your `~/.ssh/config` file. This tells ssh to actually use the IdentityFiles you specify, rather than spamming the server with all of them.

Comment: What does your private key look like?

Comment: Just use my [`github-keygen`](https://github.com/dolmen/github-keygen) tool: `github-keygen me work` (*Yes, that's all!*).

Comment: Note if you have a 'Host *' block with an 'IdentityFile' statement, to force a particular key, you need to negate the target hostname for that Host block - e.g. 'Host * !work.github.com' - that, in addition to IdentitiesOnly as @Mechanicalsnail suggests will force a particular key.

Comment: Don't forget to run `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config` if you has just created your config file. I was having trouble here.

Comment: Hi everybody, do you know how I can have git to use differente emails for different accounts? e.g. i would like to push to me.github.com using me@email.com and to work.github.com using work@email.com

Comment: @lucacerone, you just need to change the user/email in the project scope. Change to the directory and type `git config user.name 'John Smith'` and then `git config user.email john@domain.com`. This will override your global config which can be seen by `git config --global user.name`.

Comment: what is the "Host" and "Host" name should be set if I am not using github but gitlab set up at company?

Comment: When i run ~/.ssh/config I get permission denied.

Comment: @Saraschandraa It shouldn't be run. It's a config (text) file you create.

Comment: On a related note, is it possible to add a comment in the .ssh/config file without messing it up? Just curious. I assume you can add some with `#`.

Comment: but what if there isn't a separate work doman like `work.github.com` ?

Comment: I setup 3 hosts and this worked like a charm. I'm using Mac OSx High Sierra 10.13.

Comment: This can be improved with `insteadOf ` :  [Use different ssh keys for different github repos](https://public-inbox.org/git/966f577f-c4ca-46a4-d55d-817e84780324@gmail.com/)

Comment: @Paulo, as I understand this, `Host` is used to tell which configurations to use.  It is the name you use on the command line.  But `Hostname` will tell `ssh` which machine to _actually_ connect to. That is why they point/use the same `Hostname` in both `Host` Stanzas.
So, `ssh me.github,com` will actually connect to `github.com`, but use configurations from `me.github,com`.

Comment: I find it very frustrating that all the answers to this and related questions omit the last part: the git clone command to run to checkout the project using the git CLI and the ~/.ssh/config file! :(

Comment: As @Von said if you use `Host *` you should add `Host * !work.github.com`

Answer (score 219):

I recently had to do this and had to sift through all these answers and their comments to eventually piece the information together, so I'll put it all here, in one post, for your convenience:

**Step 1: ssh keys** 
Create any keypairs you'll need. In this example I've named me default/original 'id_rsa' (which is the default) and my new one 'id_rsa-work':

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "stefano@work.com"
```

**Step 2: ssh config** 
Set up multiple ssh profiles by creating/modifying **~/.ssh/config**. Note the slightly differing 'Host' values:

```
# Default GitHub
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

# Work GitHub
Host work.github.com
    HostName github.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_work
```

**Step 3: ssh-add** 
You may or may not have to do this. To check, list identity fingerprints by running:

```
$ ssh-add -l
2048 1f:1a:b8:69:cd:e3:ee:68:e1:c4:da:d8:96:7c:d0:6f stefano (RSA)
2048 6d:65:b9:3b:ff:9c:5a:54:1c:2f:6a:f7:44:03:84:3f stefano@work.com (RSA)
```

If your entries aren't there then run:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_work
```

**Step 4: test** 
To test you've done this all correctly, I suggest the following quick check:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi stefano! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

$ ssh -T git@work.github.com
Hi stefano! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Note that you'll have to change the hostname (github / work.github) depending on what key/identity you'd like to use. But now you should be good to go! :)

Comment: This is a great response. I had to use ssh-add to add both the ssh keys to utilize the config file.. Thanks :)

Comment: The only thing I like to add is when you run ssh-keygen -t rsa, it will give you a default file name, that is where you enter your custom file name.

Comment: One of best answers. Also this video helped me. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fnSRBRiQIU8&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Good post, would be nice if this post included setting your git config 'email':   https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-commit-email-address-in-git/

Comment: If anyone else is getting "error connecting to agent" when doing "ssh-agent", check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52113738/starting-ssh-agent-on-windows-10-fails-unable-to-start-ssh-agent-service-erro

Comment: What do I do if my company github repositories are something like https://github.com/somename-internal what changes do I need to make to the config file to distinguish between personal account (which will be of the form github.com) vs work repos with an extra "/somename-internal"

Answer (score 60):

Let's say `alice` is a github.com user, with 2 or more private repositories `repoN`.
For this example we'll work with just two repositories named `repo1` and `repo2`

`https://github.com/alice/repo1`

`https://github.com/alice/repo2`

You need to be to pull from these repositories without entering a passwords probably on a server, or on multiple servers.
You want to perform `git pull origin main` for example, and you want this to happen without asking for a password.

You don't like dealing with ssh-agent, you have discovered (or you're discovering now) about `~/.ssh/config` a file that let's your ssh client know what private key to use depending on Hostname and username, with a simple configuration entry that looks like this:

```
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /home/alice/.ssh/alice_github.id_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

So you went ahead and created your `(alice_github.id_rsa, alice_github.id_rsa.pub)` keypair, you then also went to your repository's `.git/config` file and you modified the url of your remote `origin` to be something like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = "ssh://git@github.com/alice/repo1.git"
```

And finally you went to the repository `Settings > Deploy keys` section and added the contents of `alice_github.id_rsa.pub`

At this point you could do your `git pull origin main` without entering a password without issue.

#### but what about the second repository?

So your instinct will be to grab that key and add it to `repo2`'s Deploy keys, but github.com will error out and tell you that the key is already being used.

Now you go and generate another key (using `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "alice@alice.com"` without passwords of course), and so that this doesn't become a mess, you will now name your keys like this:

- `repo1` keypair: `(repo1.alice_github.id_rsa, repo1.alice_github.id_rsa.pub)`
- `repo2` keypair: `(repo2.alice_github.id_rsa, repo2.alice_github.id_rsa.pub)`

You will now put the new public key on `repo2`'s Deploy keys configuration at github.com, but now you have an ssh problem to deal with.

#### How can ssh tell which key to use if the repositories are hosted on the same `github.com` domain?

Your `.ssh/config` file points to `github.com` and it doesn't know which key to use when it's time to do the pull.

So I found a trick with github.com. You can tell your ssh client that each repository lives in a different github.com subdomain, in these cases, they will be `repo1.github.com` and `repo2.github.com`

So first thing is editing the `.git/config` files on your repo clones, so they look like this instead:

For repo1

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = "ssh://git@repo1.github.com/alice/repo1.git"
```

For repo2

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = "ssh://git@repo2.github.com/alice/repo2.git"
```

And then, on your `.ssh/config` file, now you will be able to enter a configuration for each subdomain :)

```
Host repo1.github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /home/alice/.ssh/repo1.alice_github.id_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes

Host repo2.github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /home/alice/.ssh/repo2.alice_github.id_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Now you are able to `git pull origin main` without entering any passwords from both repositories.

If you have multiple machines, you could copy the keys to each of the machines and reuse them, but I'd advise doing the leg work to generate 1 key per machine and repo. You will have a lot more keys to handle, but you will be less vulnerable if one gets compromised.

Comment: Specifying the subdomain that matches the host in `.ssh/config` is the crucial step - thanks a lot for that

Comment: Nice explanation of the `Host` component, thanks

Comment: Hi I have two machines, can you tell how can I copy key from one laptop to another? copy and then rename? Does this work?

Comment: your keys are usually inside your ~/.ssh folder, just copy the files over in whatever way you can.

Comment: Good job! See the same [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77962008/7915017).

Answer (score 46):

I have 2 accounts on github, and here is what I did (on `linux`) to make it work.

### Keys

- Create 2 pair of rsa keys, via `ssh-keygen`, name them properly, so that make life easier.
- Add private keys to local agent via `ssh-add path_to_private_key`
- For each github account, upload a (distinct) public key.

---

### Configuration

**~/.ssh/config**

```
Host github-kc
    Hostname        github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile    ~/.ssh/github_rsa_kc.pub
    # LogLevel DEBUG3

Host github-abc
    Hostname        github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile    ~/.ssh/github_rsa_abc.pub
    # LogLevel DEBUG3
```

**Set remote url for repo:**

- For repo in Host `github-kc`:

  ```
  git remote set-url origin git@github-kc:kuchaguangjie/pygtrans.git
  ```
- For repo in Host `github-abc`:

  ```
  git remote set-url origin git@github-abc:abcdefg/yyy.git
  ```

---

### Explaination

**Options in `~/.ssh/config`:**

- `Host` github-<identify_specific_user> 
  Host could be any value that could identify a host plus an account,
  it don't need to be a real host,
  e.g
      `github-kc` identify one of my account on github for my local 
  laptop,

  When set remote url for a git repo, this is the value to put after `git@`, that's how a repo maps to a Host, e.g `git remote set-url origin git@github-kc:kuchaguangjie/pygtrans.git`
- 
- ***[Following are sub options of `Host`]***
- `Hostname` 
      specify the actual hostname, just use `github.com` for github,
- `User` git 
      the user is always `git` for github,
- `IdentityFile` 
      specify key to use, just put the path the a public key,
- `LogLevel` 
      specify log level to debug, if any issue, `DEBUG3` gives the most detailed info.

---

Comment: lovely -- did not need `ssh-add path_to_private_key` -- probably because the agent isn't required in this case.  The config file is explicitly defining the path to the keys.

Comment: @MarkChackerian I think you don't need `ssh-add` because your keys aren't password protected or (if you're on a Mac) the OSX keychain is handling it for you. `ssh-add` prevents you from needing to enter the passphrase every time you access your keys.

Comment: Great, to the point and what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Excellent explanation. The key here is to use "git remote set-url ..." to tell git which ssh key to use by referencing the right host!

Answer (score 20):

Use the `IdentityFile` parameter in your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github.rsa
    User petdance
```

Comment: Thanks but this isn't quite accurate.  I found the answer and shared below.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my approach will work in your case.  You can identify different users and different identity files.  Just need to give each a different Host parameter on the config stanza.

Comment: Andy, according to the link I found below I needed to drop the .com from the host.  Once I did that it worked fine.

Answer (score 18):

A possibly simpler alternative to editing the ssh config file (as suggested in all other answers), is to configure an individual repository to use a different (e.g. non-default) ssh key.

Inside the repository for which you want to use a different key, run:

```
git config core.sshCommand 'ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_anotheraccount'
```

If your key is passhprase-protected and you don't want to type your password every time, you have to add it to the ssh-agent. Here's how to do it for [ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466626/add-private-key-permanently-with-ssh-add-on-ubuntu) and here for [macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909651/svnssh-not-having-to-do-ssh-add-every-time-mac-os).

<sup>It should also be possible to scale this approach to multiple repositories using global git config and conditional includes ([see example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36296990/3937850)).</sup>

Comment: You can even configure this using `includeIf` in your global `.gitconfig`.

Comment: This answer was the most useful to me. I'd hate to have to change the URL manually every time I want to clone something, but this is easy to add to the script I'm already using to set my email address and other identity details per work directory before starting to work.

Answer (score 9):

I spent a lot of time to understand all the steps. So lets describe step by step:

1. Create new identity file using `ssh-keygen -t rsa`. Give it an alternative like `proj1.id_rsa` and hit  with no doubt because you don't need a passphrase.
2. Add new section in `.ssh/config`:

   ```
   Host proj1.github.com
       HostName github.com
       PreferredAuthentications publickey
       IdentityFile ~/.ssh/proj1.id_rsa
   ```

Take into account the first section and note that `proj1.github.com` we will back to the section later.

3. Add the identity to ssh agent `ssh-add ~/.ssh/proj1.id_rsa`
4. That what I messed first time - now when you want to clone a proj1 repo you do it using `proj1.github.com` (exactly the host from the config file).
   `git clone git@proj1.github.com`.

[A good tutorial.](https://gist.github.com/gubatron/d96594d982c5043be6d4)

*Don't mess up with hosts*

Comment: Thanks for the link to the turorial! You have a typo: the key names `id_rsa_proj1` and `proj1_id_rsa` should actually be same. You could also add the part about `.git/config` settings from the tutorial to your answer.

Comment: You still have a typo: `proj1.id_rsa` vs. `proj1_id_rsa`

Answer (score 6):

I find solution of this problem and try to explain it.
We should make change in both file `~/.ssh/config` and in `~/.gitconfig`

Let's show.

### 1. Create keys

You will need one key for each different account you will use on either GitHub or BitBucket.

Whichever site you have more identities with determines how many keys you will need.

A single key can act both as a GitHub and BitBucket key but cannot be associated with more than one BitBucket or GitHub account.

If you already have created a key in ~/.ssh/id_rsa (the default location), you may use that in place of the ~/.ssh/msmith key in my examples or you can leave that key and add additional keys for the other identities.

Create the keys and ssh-add them (make sure to enter a secure password and do not just leave it blank)

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f ~/.ssh/key1_rsa -C "msmith@example.com"
```

Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): ************
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /Users/me/.ssh/key1_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /Users/me/.ssh/key1_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
...

```
$  ssh-add ~/.ssh/key1_rsa
$  ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f ~/.ssh/key2_rsa -C "jblige@example.com"
```

Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): ************
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /Users/me/.ssh/key2_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /Users/me/.ssh/key2_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
...

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/key2_rsa
```

### 2. Setup ~/.ssh/config

Create a file in ~/.ssh/config (if it does not already exist). You must make sure it is readable only by the owner and the group and public bits are set off.

```
touch ~/.ssh/config
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config
```

We now need to add SSH configuration that specifies the github and bitbucket hostnames but with a suffix appended to qualify which key to use. We set the HostName to the correct github.com or bitbucket.org address.

Note: Linux users should either omit UseKeychain yes or add IgnoreUnknown UseKeychain (thanks soulofmischief)

```
~/.ssh/config
...

Host github.com-msmith
  HostName github.com
  UseKeychain yes
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/msmith_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes

Host bitbucket.org-msmith
  HostName bitbucket.org
  UseKeychain yes
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/msmith_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes

Host github.com-jblige
  HostName github.com
  UseKeychain yes
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/jblige_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes

Host bitbucket.org-jblige
  HostName bitbucket.org
  UseKeychain yes
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/jblige_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes

...
```

### 3. Add public keys to GitHub and BitBucket

Log into GitHub for each user and add the keys from ~/.ssh/xxxxx.pub to the respective users authorized SSH keys.

> For more information on this see:
> https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html
>
> or
>
> https://help.github.com/en/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

### 4. Create key specific .gitconfig

You will need a single directory where all code that corresponds to a given key will be checked out to.

I prefer to keep all those directories in one directory in my home ~/src and I name them according to the account name associated with the key

```
mkdir -p ~/src/msmith
mkdir -p ~/src/jblige
```

In each directory put a .gitconfig file.

```
~/src/msmith/.gitconfig
...
[user]
  email = msmith@example.com
    
[url "git@bitbucket.org-msmith"]
  insteadOf = git@bitbucket.org
  
[url "git@github.com-msmith"]
  insteadOf = git@github.com
~/src/jblige/.gitconfig
...
[user]
  email = jblige@example.com
  signingkey = ABCD1234
  
[url "git@bitbucket.org-jblige"]
  insteadOf = git@bitbucket.org
  
[url "git@github.com-jblige"]
  insteadOf = git@github.com
  
[commit]
  gpgsign = true
```

This way, I use the correct email address for both keys and have even set up automatic commit signing for jblige. I also rewrite all the hostnames for the original SSH connections to the correctly suffixed hostnames I created in the SSH config file.

For more information about GPG signing see:

> https://help.github.com/en/articles/signing-commits
>
> or
>
> https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/using-gpg-keys-913477014.html

### 5. Setup Git config includeif

To activate the .gitconfig files in ~/src/*, edit the .gitconfig file in your home directory and add an includeif statement for each of the .gitconfig files referencing the directory they are in

```
~/.gitconfig
...

[includeif "gitdir:~/src/msmith/"]
    path = ~/src/msmith/.gitconfig
    
[includeif "gitdir:~/src/jblige/"]
    path = ~/src/jblige/.gitconfig
```

Do not forget the trailing slash in the [includeif "gitdir:... statement.

### 6. Cloning the repositories

You then clone the code using the SSH clone address (i.e. git@bitbucket.org... or git@github.com..., not https://bitbucket.org... nor https://github.com...) into the directory that corresponds to the key you want to use for that clone.

```
$  cd ~/src/msmith
$  git clone git@github.com:someuser/somerepo.git
...
```

Because of the rewriting, git will actually attempt to clone using the suffixed address corresponding to the configuration in the SSH config file but because of the SSH configuration it will use the original hostname when actually connecting to the host ensuring you use the right key.

All commits/pulls/pushes to/from those repositories will use the corresponding config/key/account.

Comment: One thing to add here is that `gitdir` is a glob pattern, so your clones don't have to be a direct child of that path but could be a grandchild.
E.g. I have a <parent> directory for my uni work, which is where my included .gitignore lives, then each unit that I have lives under that with their respective files/folder structure. A git repo might not be encountered until 3 or 4 levels down.
So long as <parent> is in the path, it will include the correct .gitignore.

Answer (score 5):

In my case none of the solutions above solved my issue, but ssh-agent does.  Basically, I did the following:

1. Generate key pair using ssh-keygen shown below.  It will generate a key pair (in this example `.\keyfile` and `.\keyfile.pub`)

   `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "yourname@yourdomain" -f keyfile`
2. Upload `keyfile.pub` to the git provider
3. Start ssh-agent on your machine (you can check with `ps -ef | grep ssh-agent` to see if it is running already)
4. Run `ssh-add .\keyfile` to add credentials
5. Now you can run `git clone git@provider:username/project.git`

Answer (score 4):

Simplest way to use multiple Git accounts and clone without any changes would be to add your username to the ssh config.

1. Open `~/.ssh/config`. Create if one doesn't exist
2. Add your host entry as following

```
Host github.com:<YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME>
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<YOUR_SSH_KEY_FILENAME>
```

Replace **<YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME>** with your desired github username (personal or work) Replace **<YOUR_SSH_KEY_FILENAME>** with your keyfile name in .ssh folder (ex: id_ed25519).
Add a host record for each of the github account you want to maintain.

Now git clone would be simple as `git clone github.com:<YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME>/your-repo.git`. No custom gihub domains to remember when cloning ;-)

Made a gist with further information https://gist.github.com/udantha/fed5439630eaf4651272f4fba6e1c6a3

Comment: This is actually on of the best answers. With the `:<YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME>` part being really important. The reason being is that let's say you want to reference a private git repo as a package in your package.json file, if you end up having to use something like:

`"package" : "git+ssh://git@new-host:<user>/<repo>.git"`

Which means everyone has to update their .ssh config file to match yours. But if you include the `:<YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME>` then you can be assured everyone can access it directly whether or not the have multiple ssh keys or not.

Comment: But I can have different username / organisation where I want to push directly. In that case we have add multiple `host:username` combination. Directory based solution works well instead of configuring ssh config file update git config file `core.sshcommand = "ssh -i ~/.ssh/<ssh-key>"`

Answer (score 3):

As a complement of @stefano 's answer,
It is better to use command with `-f` when generate a new SSH key for another account,

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa_work -C "your@mail.com"
```

Since `id_rsa_work` file doesn't exist in path `~/.ssh/`, and I create this file manually, and it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

I posted the technique I use to deal with these [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9552116/1633251)

Answer (score 2):

I used,

```
Host github.com
   HostName github.com
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_rsa
   User abc@gmail.com
```

It wokred fine.

Use the above setting in your .ssh/config file for different rsa keys for different usernames.

Answer (score 1):

This is the only config that worked for me to be able to use two GitHub accounts with different SSH keys.

Replace `id_ed25519` (representing my work SSH key) and `id_ed25519-personal` (representing my personal SSH key) with your SSH keys' filenames.

```
Host github.com
IdentitiesOnly yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519-personal
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to edit your ssh config and deal with weird remote URLs at all. Leverage gitconfig!

```
# ~/.gitconfig, only used in this directory
[includeIf "gitdir:/home/user/work/"]
    path = ~/.work.gitconfig

# ~/.work.gitconfig
[user]
        email = "my_other_email@address.com"
        name = John Doe
[core]
        sshCommand = ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_work # use my other ssh key
```