# Can I specify multiple users for myself in .gitconfig?

Tags: git, git-config

In my `~/.gitconfig`, I list my personal email address under `[user]`, since that's what I want to use for Github repos.

But, I've recently started using git for work, too. My company's git repo allows me to commit, but when it sends out announcements of new changesets, it says they are from Anonymous because it doesn't recognize the email address in my `.gitconfig` - at least, that's my theory.

Is it possible to specify multiple `[user]` definitions in `.gitconfig`? Or is there some other way to override the default `.gitconfig` for a certain directory? In my case, I check out all work code in `~/worksrc/` - is there a way to specify a `.gitconfig` for only that directory (and its subdirectories)?

Comment: See [git-config#FILES](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html#FILES).

Comment: I'm surprised that your company server would do that - it would have to CHANGE the sha of your commit for that to work.  If you make a commit to a local checkout, what username do you see?

Comment: @Alex: Presumably the notification hook is trying to match the author information (email, perhaps) with some other list/database, maybe in order to canonicalize it, maybe looking for some other information. Obviously not the best approach for this particular case, though!

Comment: @Alex: Forgot the important bit there - it could easily just be a name on the email notification, not actually changing anything on the commit.

Comment: You can use a git-hook to automate this recurring work: https://github.com/DrVanScott/git-clone-init

Comment: Please accept this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43654115/482899. It's best solution since git 2.13.

Comment: could use the  pattern `[includeIf "gitdir:D:/workCode/**"]`

Comment: @northtree - it's a great answer. Unfortunately, it seems like Xcode does not 'play nicely' when that configuration is present, so I had to remove it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75151821/906192 In any case, both answers here have merit :)

Answer (score 1325, accepted):

You can configure an individual repo to use a specific user / email address which overrides the global configuration.  From the root of the repo, run

```
git config user.name "Your Name Here"
git config user.email your@email.com
```

whereas the default user / email is configured in your ~/.gitconfig

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name Here"
git config --global user.email your@email.com
```

Comment: you can see the effects of these settings in the `.git/config` file

Comment: i tried this at work to specify my work-specific name/email, but i still seem to be getting emails to my personal account that i tied to the --global git command.  I've never used this feature before, but should it send an email (if there is one) to the first found user.email and not trickly up into the --global?  does it take some time once i set the local user.name/email or should it be instnataneous?

Comment: @dtan see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665337/git-pushing-as-wrong-user/6665231#6665231

Comment: You can manually edit those config files with `git config --edit` and `git config --global --edit`. And in case you missed Abizern’s [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220416/can-i-specify-multiple-users-for-myself-in-gitconfig#comment4566646_4220493), a repository’s config file is at `<repo-root>/.git/config`.

Comment: You should also unset **GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL** and **GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL** (and *_NAME) as they will override the local settings

Comment: Is there a way to do this for all repos in a given folder, rather than for individual repos? See my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307793/set-git-config-values-for-all-child-folders

Comment: After changing the specific repo config, git commands are still executed with my global setting. Is that normal?

Comment: People facing problem even after this, if you are using ssh, ensure you have proper ssh keys for your other email account set in your git hub account.

Comment: See [this answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43654115/3507206) for more upto-date solution with `Git 2.13` released today.

Comment: Note that Apple's Keychain Access or Windows' Credentials Manager may have cached your previous username/password

Comment: This doesn't work, if you have `.netrc` with different credentials.  Git ignores whatever information there is in your local configuration and sends random authentication to the server owned by someone else. Nice job.

Answer (score 986):

Since git **2.13**, it is possible to solve this using newly introduced [Conditional includes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_conditional_includes).

An example:

Global config *~/.gitconfig*

```
[user]
    name = John Doe
    email = john@doe.tld

[includeIf "gitdir:~/work/"]
    path = ~/work/.gitconfig
```

Work specific config *~/work/.gitconfig*

```
[user]
    email = john.doe@company.tld
```

---

Remember that `[includeIf...]` should follows default `[user]` at the top.

Comment: This is the best answer now that git 2.13 has been released.

Comment: Would this solution work for all subdirectories within the one specified in the include statement, assuming they have no .gitconfig files of their own? I would think so, but so far testing hasn't borne this out.

Comment: @Gary Yes, according to my experience and the docs:
“If the pattern ends with /, ** will be automatically added. For example, the pattern foo/ becomes foo/**. In other words, it matches "foo" and everything inside, recursively.”,
“; include for all repositories inside $HOME/to/group
[includeIf "gitdir:~/to/group/"]”

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I did have to go to 2.13.1 docs to find out more about the `includeIf` section: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.13.1#_conditional_includes

Comment: @gligoran There seems to be something wrong with the website. It says there are no changes between 2.13.0 and 2.13.1 version of git-config manpage, yet the 2.13.0 one doesn't mention includeIf. :-(

Comment: It is mentioned briefly here: https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.13.0/Documentation/RelNotes/2.13.0.txt

Comment: The ***gitdir*** should include the last '/'.

Comment: Do not replace the `~` by `$HOME` as git will already expand it for you as explained here : https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-pathname

Comment: This answer I think better addresses the original issue, that is : specify multiple identities at once, in the main ~/.gitconfig, without having to specify them explicitly for each repositories belonging to the same "class" (eg: all corporate work below ~/corporate, and all personal below ~/personal, etc..)
For me it should be accepted as the best answer, as of 2019

Comment: For windows users, the .gitconfig file is located in the folder %USERPROFILE%, which for me is C:\users\matt.

Also note that the paths specified ARE case sensitive. Mine looks like this:

[includeIf "gitdir:C:/code/MyCompany/"]
 path = C:/code/MyCompany/.gitconfig

Comment: You can check that that it works recursively by running `git config --list` in different directories. In subdirectories of `~/work/` that contain a git repository, the `includeIf` takes effect. Note that in subdirectories of `~/work/` that don't contain a git repository, the `includeIf` is not executed.

Comment: on windows it should have different path?

Comment: Run `git config user.email` in a git repository in the work path to see if it works.

Comment: Looks like it's also possible to configure the credential helper in the referenced imports: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials#_avoiding_repetition

Comment: what should I do if I need to clone with a different username and email, when the project folder doesn't yet exist on the machine? How can I switch the username and email prior to clone?

Comment: @mishap Why would you need to do that? Username and e-mail isn't being used during clone.

Comment: @TomášJanoušek, ok, so my problem is somewhere else, I have two github accounts and configured them in `~/.ssh/config`, same as in @Kaleem Ullah answer along with two separate pairs of private and public keys. But I have no clue how to switch from one account to the other before ssh clone. Git seems to be stuck on my home account. Testing both hosts with `ssh -T [host]` responds with authenticating home account username. Cloning work repo with correct host from `~/.ssh/config` results in access rights error.

Comment: the above does not seem to work when a repository contains submodules. One still needs to explicitly do `git config --local user.email me@my-work.com` for each submodule. Is there a solution for that case ?

Comment: In GitHub Desktop `File > Options > Git` it shows an error and tells me that I am using the global config settings. However, running `git config user.email` within my personal repo shows different. After a test commit as well, it works. You can ignore what GitHub Desktop shows.

Comment: On windows I had to replace `"gitdir:~/work/"` with `"gitdir:**/work/"` and specify the full path to the new gitconfig

Comment: Make sure  all the capitalized & small letters in the path are written exactly as they are in your system, else this won't work. use `pwd` command to copy/paste your directory path properly if needed.

Comment: Would it be possible to use `hasconfig:remote.*.url:` to specify an email globally any repo that uses the company git host or domain?

Comment: Example: `[includeIf "hasconfig:remote.*.url:https://gitlab.mycompany.com/**"]`

Comment: check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48088291/6908282) and [this gist](https://gist.github.com/AnweshGangula/054bc1c52a6e790b0b33e68efd862323) for detailed steps on how to do it. And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43920482/6908282) on how to use `includeIf` in windows

Comment: if you need to change ssh key between accounts in you work .gitconfig you can add a `[core]` section with `sshCommand = ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_example -F /dev/null` entry

Answer (score 124):

Or you can add following information in your local `.git/config` file

```
[user]  
    name = Your Name
    email = your.email@gmail.com
```

Comment: ...which is the manual way to do what the commands recommended by @discomurray do for you.

Comment: is it possible to add multiple lines of this per remote?

Comment: @AbelCallejo Yes, you can specify multiple `[user]` sections. Also, note that git can stores the username & credentials inside `Credential Manager` on Windows OS.

Answer (score 123):

**One command github accounts switch**

This solution takes the form of a single git alias. Once executed, the current project user will be attached to another account

**Generate ssh keys**

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "rinquin.arnaud@gmail.com" -f '/Users/arnaudrinquin/.ssh/id_rsa'

[...]

ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "arnaud.rinquin@wopata.com" -f '/Users/arnaudrinquin/.ssh/id_rsa_pro'
```

**Link them to your GitHub / Bitbucket accounts**

1. copy default public key `pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
2. login to your GitHub acount
3. paste the key in the `add SSH key` github page
4. copy other public key `pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa_pro.pub`
5. repeat and adapt steps 2 to 4 for every other account

**Step 1. Automatic ssh key switching.**

We can configure `ssh` to send a use a specific encryption key depending on the `host`. The nice thing is that you can have several aliases for the same `hostname`.

See this example `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
# Default GitHub
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

# Professional github alias
Host github_pro
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_pro
```

**git remote configuration**

You can now use these aliases in the git remotes by changing `git@github.com` by `git@github_pro`.

You can either change your existing projects remotes (using something like `git remote set-url origin git@github_pro:foo/bar.git`) or adapt them directly when cloning them.

```
git clone git@github.com:ArnaudRinquin/atom-zentabs.git
```

**using alias, it become:**

`git clone git@github_pro:ArnaudRinquin/atom-zentabs.git`

**Step 2. Changing git user.email**

Git config settings can be global or per project. In our case, we want a per project settings. It is very easy to change it:

```
git config user.email 'arnaud.rinquin@wopata.com'
```

While this is easy, it takes way to long for the developers we are. We can write a very simple git alias for that.

We are going to add it to the `~/.gitconfig` file.

```
[user]
    name = Arnaud Rinquin
    email = rinquin.arnaud@gmail.com

...

[alias]
    setpromail = "config user.email 'arnaud.rinquin@wopata.com'"
```

Then, all we have to do is `git setpromail` to have our email changed for this project only.

**Step 3. One command switch please?!**

Wouldn’t it be nice to switch from default account to a specified one with a single parameter-less command? This is definitely possible. This command will have two steps:

- change current project remotes to the chosen aliases
- change current project user.email config

We already have a one command solution for the second step, but the first one is way harder.
One command remote host change

Here comes the solution in the form of another git alias command to add to your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
  changeremotehost = !sh -c \"git remote -v | grep '$1.*fetch' | sed s/..fetch.// | sed s/$1/$2/ | xargs git remote set-url\"
```

This allows changing all remotes from one host to another (the alias). See the example:

```
$ > git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:ArnaudRinquin/arnaudrinquin.github.io.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:ArnaudRinquin/arnaudrinquin.github.io.git (push)

$ > git changeremotehost github.com github_pro

$ > git remote -v
origin  git@github_pro:ArnaudRinquin/arnaudrinquin.github.io.git (fetch)
origin  git@github_pro:ArnaudRinquin/arnaudrinquin.github.io.git (push)
```

**Combine them all**

We now just have to combine the two commands into one, this is quite easy. See how I also integrate bitbucket host switching.

```
[alias]
  changeremotehost = !sh -c \"git remote -v | grep '$1.*fetch' | sed s/..fetch.// | sed s/$1/$2/ | xargs git remote set-url\"
  setpromail = "config user.email 'arnaud.rinquin@wopata.com'"
  gopro = !sh -c \"git changeremotehost github.com github_pro && git changeremotehost bitbucket.com bitbucket_pro && git setpromail\"
```

[Source Link -Github](https://github.com/ArnaudRinquin/blog/blob/master/2014-03-11-one-command-github-account-switch.md)

[Source Link -Tutorial](http://arnaudrinquin.github.io/worflow/2014/03/11/fast-github-account-switch/)

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks. I work with a bunch of repos per email so my `setpromail` alias does a `config --global` instead (and I have other set aliases for setting different email addresses). It works!

Comment: For those 2 different accounts how can I sign with different gpg keys ? I have 2x gpg keys for 2x github accounts and would like to sign differently.   "git config --global user.signingkey xxxx"

Comment: This answer is awesome. I nearly didn't read it because I thought I found what from the other answer. Definitely deserves more upvotes. PS. It is even better when combined with `useConfigOnly = true` from the other answer.

Comment: Is not IdentifyFile, it is IdenfityFile.

Comment: The link to the tutorial is no longer valid.  I found it at https://github.com/ArnaudRinquin/blog/blob/master/2014-03-11-one-command-github-account-switch.md

Comment: Ohh dude you just saved my life thank you very much now i can login multiple origin and accounts

Comment: I think the order of this is potentially wrong. You can't clone a repo if your global git user isn't tied to the repo. So does that mean you have to globally switch to clone a different user's repo and then globally switch back to your default and then do the local git username switch?

Answer (score 54):

With [conditional includes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_conditional_includes) in Git 2.13, it is now possible to have multiple user/email coexist on one machine with little work.

`user.gitconfig` has my personal name and email. `work-user.gitconfig` has my work name and email. Both files are at `~` path.

So my personal name/email applies by default. For `c:/work/` dir, my work name/email is applied. For `c:/work/github/` dir, my personal name/email is applied. This works as the last setting gets applied.

```
# ~/.gitconfig
[include]
    path = user.gitconfig
[includeIf "gitdir/i:c:/work/"]
    path = work-user.gitconfig
[includeIf "gitdir/i:c:/work/github/"]
    path = user.gitconfig
```

`gitdir` is case-sensitive and `gitdir/i` is case-insensitive.

`"gitdir/i:github/"` would apply the conditional include for any directory with `github` in its path.

Comment: While your answer is appreciated and good Tomáš Janoušek gave the same 20 days before you. Please consider deleting this answer.

Comment: @Hedge Yes, I upvoted his answer, but it took me a while to configure on windows and that's where `gitdir/i` helped me out (which his answer does not mention).

Comment: The particular way @hIpPy implemented this directly applied to my use case and made it that much easier to follow than Tomas' answer. I upvoted both.

Comment: As an alternative, one can use the `includeIf` filter `hasconfig` to include configuration files based on the `remote` url. This allows to configure based on repo ownership instead of local organization. Example: `[includeIf "hasconfig:remote.*.url:*github.com:my-company-org-A/*"]`. This is notably useful for people working with Github Enterprise Cloud Organizations.

Answer (score 47):

After getting some inspiration from [Orr Sella's blog post](http://orrsella.com/2013/08/10/git-using-different-user-emails-for-different-repositories/) I wrote a pre-commit hook (resides in `~/.git/templates/hooks`) which would set specific usernames and e-mail addresses based on the information inside a local repositorie's `./.git/config`:

You have to place the path to the template directory into your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[init]
    templatedir = ~/.git/templates
```

Then each `git init` or `git clone` will pick up that hook and will apply the user data during the next `git commit`. If you want to apply the hook to already exisiting repos then just run a `git init` inside the repo in order to reinitialize it.

Here is the hook I came up with (it still needs some polishing - suggestions are welcome).
Save it either as

```
~/.git/templates/hooks/pre_commit
```

or

```
~/.git/templates/hooks/post-checkout
```

and make sure it is executable: `chmod +x ./post-checkout || chmod +x ./pre_commit`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# -------- USER CONFIG
# Patterns to match a repo's "remote.origin.url" - beginning portion of the hostname
git_remotes[0]="Github"
git_remotes[1]="Gitlab"

# Adjust names and e-mail addresses
local_id_0[0]="my_name_0"
local_id_0[1]="my_email_0"

local_id_1[0]="my_name_1"
local_id_1[1]="my_email_1"

local_fallback_id[0]="${local_id_0[0]}"
local_fallback_id[1]="${local_id_0[1]}"


# -------- FUNCTIONS
setIdentity()
{
    local current_id local_id

    current_id[0]="$(git config --get --local user.name)"
    current_id[1]="$(git config --get --local user.email)"

    local_id=("$@")

    if [[ "${current_id[0]}" == "${local_id[0]}" &&
          "${current_id[1]}" == "${local_id[1]}" ]]; then
        printf " Local identity is:\n"
        printf "»  User: %s\n»  Mail: %s\n\n" "${current_id[@]}"
    else
        printf "»  User: %s\n»  Mail: %s\n\n" "${local_id[@]}"
        git config --local user.name "${local_id[0]}"
        git config --local user.email "${local_id[1]}"
    fi

    return 0
}

# -------- IMPLEMENTATION
current_remote_url="$(git config --get --local remote.origin.url)"

if [[ "$current_remote_url" ]]; then

    for service in "${git_remotes[@]}"; do

        # Disable case sensitivity for regex matching
        shopt -s nocasematch

        if [[ "$current_remote_url" =~ $service ]]; then
            case "$service" in

                "${git_remotes[0]}" )
                    printf "\n»» An Intermission\n»  %s repository found." "${git_remotes[0]}"
                    setIdentity "${local_id_0[@]}"
                    exit 0
                    ;;

                "${git_remotes[1]}" )
                    printf "\n»» An Intermission\n»  %s repository found." "${git_remotes[1]}"
                    setIdentity "${local_id_1[@]}"
                    exit 0
                    ;;

                * )
                    printf "\n»  pre-commit hook: unknown error\n» Quitting.\n"
                    exit 1
                    ;;

            esac
        fi
    done
else
    printf "\n»» An Intermission\n»  No remote repository set. Using local fallback identity:\n"
    printf "»  User: %s\n»  Mail: %s\n\n" "${local_fallback_id[@]}"

    # Get the user's attention for a second
    sleep 1

    git config --local user.name "${local_fallback_id[0]}"
    git config --local user.email "${local_fallback_id[1]}"
fi

exit 0
```

---

EDIT:

So I rewrote the hook as a hook and command in Python. Additionally it's possible to call the script as a Git command (`git passport`), too. Also it's possible to define an arbitrary number of IDs inside a configfile (`~/.gitpassport`) which are selectable on a prompt. You can find the project at github.com: [git-passport - A Git command and hook written in Python to manage multiple Git accounts / user identities](https://github.com/frace/git-passport).

Comment: This works neatly. However, it worked better for me by making this a post-checkout (instead of post-commit) hook. My suggestions to improve this answer are, mention that: 1. the snippet needs to be saved as ~/.git/templates/hooks/post-checkout and be given permission `chmod +x post-checkout`, 2. `git_remotes` values are beginning portion of the entire hostname, e.g. `git@github.com`, 3. `local_id` values should be edited by user to respective names and email addresses.

Comment: @ShantanuKumar Thanks for your comment. I adjusted the answer as you proposed. Maybe I will rewrite the script in Python soon.

Comment: Added support for regular expressions and for repositories without remotes. For easy download all merged [here](https://github.com/cfi/git-passport/tree/dev_all). Regexps to distinguish identities for different projects on the same service. And supporting remoteless repos with e.g. a default identity makes sense if you `git init` new projects from an IDE such as `eclipse` (which cannot handle interactive pre-commit triggers)

Answer (score 31):

If you do not want to have a default email address ([email address links to a github user](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git/)), you can configure that you want to be asked. How you can do that depends on the version of git you use, see below.

The (intended) drawback is that you have to configure your email address (and your name) once for every repository. So, you cannot forget to do it.

### Version < 2.7.0

```
[user]
    name = Your name
    email = "(none)"
```

in your global configuration `~/.gitconfig` as stated in a comment by Dan Aloni in [Orr Sella's blog post](https://orrsella.com/2013/08/10/git-using-different-user-emails-for-different-repositories/). When trying to do the first commit in a repository, git fails with the nice message:

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got '(none)')
```

The name is taken from the global config when the email address is set locally (the message is not perfectly accurate).

### 2.7.0 ≤ Version < 2.8.0

The behaviour in versions < 2.7.0 was not intended and fixed with 2.7.0. You can still use a pre-commit hook as described in [Orr Sella's blog post](https://orrsella.com/2013/08/10/git-using-different-user-emails-for-different-repositories/). This solution works also for other versions, but the other solutions not for this version.

### Version ≥ 2.8.0

[Dan Aloni added](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-v9-ident-add-user-useConfigOnly-boolean-for-when-ident-shouldn-t-be-guessed-tp7647404.html) an option to achieve that behaviour (see [release notes](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.8.0.txt)). Use it with:

```
[user]
    useConfigOnly = true
```

To make it work you may not give a name or email address in the global config. Then, at the first commit, you get an error message

```
fatal: user.useConfigOnly set but no name given
```

So the message is not very instructive, but since you set the option explicitly, you should know what to do. In contrast to the solution of versions < 2.7.0, you always have to set both name and email manually with

```
$ git config user.name "Your Name"
$ git config user.email "your@email.com"
```

which sets your name and email only in the current repository.

Comment: I use this method for a few months, it worked great. I have multiple email addresses (personal, work) and I do not want to have a "default" one configured in global gitconfig. With special value "(none)" git will prompt me to provide a valid address every time I spin up a new repo, instead of guessing one based on username and hostname (which is annoying and I need to --amend it). 

However, recently with upgraded version of Git (2.7.0, maybe earlier), I find out that special value "(none)" does not trigger fatal errors any more. Instead it will just use "John Doe <(none)>" as is ...

Comment: @wzyboy: Oh, you are right. I used `git bisect` to find that commit [19ce497c...](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/commit/?id=19ce497cf594a3c01af33a65b27b19e7459212d6) introduced this behaviour. However, independent of the version (2.5 - 2.7) I can use `email =` (with no argument) in the config and it shows the same behaviour as `email = "(none)"` in old versions. Can you confirm this? If so, I'll edit my answer. I am just sceptical as it seems so obvious and I did not use it before.

Comment: I tried `email =` in 2.7.0, Git still guesses email address based on username and hostname. I now use `pre-commit` approach in Sella's blog. I also notified the Dan Aloni who came up with the `"(none)"` idea in Sella's post and he filed up a patch to formally implement this as a feature: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/285301

Comment: since git-2.8: The "user.useConfigOnly" configuration variable can be used to force the user to always set user.email & user.name https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.8.0.txt

Comment: @rofrol Thanks for the info. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 18):

Another option to get `git` to work with multiple names / emails is by aliasing `git` and using the `-c` flag to override the global and repository-specific config.

For example, by defining an alias:

```sh
alias git='/usr/bin/git -c user.name="Your name" -c user.email="name@example.com"'
```

To see whether it works, simply type `git config user.email`:

```sh
$ git config user.email
name@example.com
```

Instead of an alias, you could also put a custom `git` executable within your `$PATH`.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/git -c user.name="Your name" -c user.email="name@example.com" "$@"
```

An advantage of these method over a repository-specific `.git/config` is that it applies to every `git` repository when the custom `git` program is active. In this way, you can easily switch between users/names without modifying any (shared) configuration.

Answer (score 18):

After reading all the answers, that's the solution I came with:

**Scenario:**

- Local OS: Linux (bash)
- two accounts on GitHub (work/personal)
- ssh access with different keys
- my work account will be the "main" one (so it doesn't need custom configuration)

**Configuration:**

1. Set a *"fake"* host, which allows me to select the proper SSH keypair.
   At `~/.ssh/config`:

   ```sh
   # Personal GitHub account
   Host github-personal
     HostName github.com
     User git
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal
     IdentitiesOnly yes
   ```
2. *"Tell"* git it should use a custom configuration within a given directory subtree:
   At `~/.gitconfig`:

   ```sh
   # My personal projects
   [includeIf "gitdir/i:~/REPOS/PERSONAL/"]
      path = ~/REPOS/PERSONAL/personal.gitconfig
   ```
3. Finally, my config at `~/REPOS/PERSONAL/personal.gitconfig`:

   ```sh
   # gitconfig for personal projects
   [user]
     email = personalemail@example.com

   [url "git@github-personal"]
     insteadOf = git@github.com
   ```

Once the three above are in place, I can clone a personal repo like this:

```sh
user@host:~/REPOS/PERSONAL$ git clone git@github.com:jmnavarrol/python-multigit.git
Cloning in 'python-multigit'...
(...)
user@host:~/REPOS/PERSONAL$ cd python-multigit && git remote -v
origin  git@github-personal:jmnavarrol/python-multigit.git (fetch)
origin  git@github-personal:jmnavarrol/python-multigit.git (push)
user@host:~/REPOS/PERSONAL/python-multigit$
```

The addition of the url rewriting at `~/REPOS/PERSONAL/personal.gitconfig`...

```sh
[url "git@github-personal"]
  insteadOf = git@github.com
```

...is what allows me referencing the repo just by its *"standard"* URL in scripts, subrepos (i.e. the case of [python-multigit itself](https://github.com/jmnavarrol/python-multigit) -yes, lame attempt at a bit of self-promotion) without risking using the *"wrong"* URLs, therefore, the wrong authentication.

My two cents.

Comment: Note that just doing `Host github.com` instead of a unique identifier will allow you to use `git@github.com` just fine

Answer (score 17):

git aliases (and sections in git configs) to the rescue!

add an alias (from command line):

```
git config --global alias.identity '! git config user.name "$(git config user.$1.name)"; git config user.email "$(git config user.$1.email)"; :'
```

then, set, for example

```
git config --global user.github.name "your github username"
git config --global user.github.email your@github.email
```

and in a new or cloned repo you can run this command:

```
git identity github
```

This solution isn't automatic, but unsetting user and email in your global `~/.gitconfig` and setting `user.useConfigOnly` to `true` would force git to remind you to set them manually in each new or cloned repo.

```
git config --global --unset user.name
git config --global --unset user.email
git config --global user.useConfigOnly true
```

Comment: I like your solution; however, when I unset my global it just makes the commit with my computer's host name rather than having git remind me to set them in any given repo :(

Answer (score 16):

This answer is partially inspired by the post by @Saucier, but I was looking for an automated way to set `user.name` and `user.email` on a per repo basis, based on the remote, that was a little more light weight than the git-passport package that he developed.  Also h/t to @John for the useConfigOnly setting.  Here is my solution:

`.gitconfig` changes:

```
[github]
    name = <github username>
    email = <github email>
[gitlab]
    name = <gitlab username>
    email = <gitlab email>
[init]
    templatedir = ~/.git-templates
[user]
    useConfigOnly = true
```

post-checkout [hook](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) which should be saved to the following path: `~/.git-templates/hooks/post-checkout`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# make regex matching below case insensitive
shopt -s nocasematch

# values in the services array should have a corresponding section in
# .gitconfig where the 'name' and 'email' for that service are specified
remote_url="$( git config --get --local remote.origin.url )"
services=(
    'github'
    'gitlab'
)

set_local_user_config() {
    local service="${1}"
    local config="${2}"
    local service_config="$( git config --get ${service}.${config} )"
    local local_config="$( git config --get --local user.${config} )"

    if [[ "${local_config}" != "${service_config}" ]]; then
        git config --local "user.${config}" "${service_config}"
        echo "repo 'user.${config}' has been set to '${service_config}'"
    fi
}

# if remote_url doesn't contain the any of the values in the services
# array the user name and email will remain unset and the
# user.useConfigOnly = true setting in .gitconfig will prompt for those
# credentials and prevent commits until they are defined
for s in "${services[@]}"; do
    if [[ "${remote_url}" =~ "${s}" ]]; then
        set_local_user_config "${s}" 'name'
        set_local_user_config "${s}" 'email'
        break
    fi
done
```

I use different credentials for github and gitlab, but those references in the code above could be replaced or augmented with any service that you use.  In order to have the post-checkout hook automatically set the user name and email locally for a repo after a checkout make sure the service name appears in the remote url, add it to the services array in the `post-checkout` script and create a section for it in your `.gitconfig` that contains your user name and email for that service.

If none of the service names appear in the remote url or the repo doesn't have a remote the user name and email will not be set locally.  In these cases the `user.useConfigOnly` setting will be in play which will not allow you to make commits until the user name and email are set at the repo level, and will prompt the user to configure that information.

Comment: Great solution. Do not forget to `chmod 755` the hook script. Otherwise, it will be copied but never executed.

Answer (score 16):

Here are the complete steps after reading many answers here

**How to set up Multiple SSH Keys settings for different github account**

You might want to start checking your currently saved keys

```
$ ssh-add -l
```

If you decide to delete all cached keys before (**optional, carefull about this**)

```
$ ssh-add -D
```

Then you can create a ssh pub/priv key linked to each email/account that you wish/need to use

```
$ cd ~/.ssh
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "work@company.com" <-- save it as "id_rsa_work"
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "pers@email.com" <-- save it as "id_rsa_pers"
```

After performing this commands you will have the following files created

```
~/.ssh/id_rsa_work      
~/.ssh/id_rsa_work.pub

~/.ssh/id_rsa_pers
~/.ssh/id_rsa_pers.pub
```

Make sure **authentication agent** is running

```
$ eval `ssh-agent -s`
```

Add the generated keys as following (from the ~/.ssh folder)

```
$ ssh-add id_rsa_work
$ ssh-add id_rsa_pers
```

Now you can check your saved keys again

```
$ ssh-add -l
```

Now you **need** to add the generated public keys to your github/bickbuket server Acces Keys

Clone each of the repos to different folders

Go to the folder where the user **work** will work and execute this

```
$ git config user.name "Working Hard"
$ git config user.email "work@company.com"
```

Just to see what this does check the contents of the ".git/config"

Go to the folder where the user **pers** will work and execute this

```
$ git config user.name "Personal Account"
$ git config user.email "pers@email.com"
```

Just to see what this does check the contents of the ".git/config"

After all this you will be able to commit your personal and work code by just switching between those two folders

In case you are using Git Bash and need to generate ssh keys under Windows follow this steps:

https://support.automaticsync.com/hc/en-us/articles/202357115-Generating-an-SSH-Key-on-Windows

Answer (score 9):

There is a simple solution that seems to work well for avoiding mistakes.

Simply remove the `[user]` section from your `~/.gitconfig`, which will prevent you from making any commits without setting `user.name` for each repository.

In your `~/.bashrc`, add some simple aliases for the user and email:

```
alias ggmail='git config user.name "My Name";git config user.email me@gmail.com'
alias gwork='git config user.name "My Name";git config user.email me@work.job'
```

Comment: Not great cause you will duplicate the configuration in every git repo

Answer (score 5):

**Windows Environment**

Additional this can be modified from `Git Extensions --> Settings --> Global Settings`, if you have it installed in your systems.

[gitextensions-latest-release](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/releases/latest)

Right Click on a folder/directory in Windows Environment to access these settings.
[image]

**Update** : *How to switch/maintain multiple settings in Version 2.49*
[image: How to switch/maintain multiple settings in Version 2.49]

Comment: How does this address multiple users, instead of just editing them?

Comment: @D_N Updated with new screenshot with options to switch settings.

Comment: Open local repo folder and select git-config from navigation menu then click the local repo tab, the contents will be applied to $local_repo_path/.git/config as above answer.

Answer (score 4):

**`GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL` + local `.bashrc`**

`.bashrc_local`: don't track this file, put it only on your work computer:

```
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL='me@work.com'
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL"
```

`.bashrc`: track this file, make it the same on both work and home computers:

```
F="$HOME/.bashrc_local"
if [ -r "$F" ]; then
    . "$F"
fi
```

I'm using https://github.com/technicalpickles/homesick to sync my dotfiles.

If only gitconfig would accept environment variables: [Shell variable expansion in git config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262010/shell-variable-expansion-in-git-config)

Answer (score 3):

Prior to following the below steps, you must have multiple ssh keys. Those can be generated using [here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) command

Steps

1. Go to c:\users\Your User\.ssh
2. touch config
3. Configure ssh keys per domain

[image: config file]

4. Go to git repo using gitbash.
5. Configure username and name per repo `"git config user.email="abc@gmail.com"`
6. Configure name per repo. `git config user.name="Mo Sh"`
7. Execute git commands. it would pick SSH keys automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is a simple hack, but it is useful. Just generate 2 ssh keys like below.

```
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/GowthamSai/.ssh/id_rsa): work
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in damsn.
Your public key has been saved in damsn.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:CrsKDJWVVek5GTCqmq8/8RnwvAo1G6UOmQFbzddcoAY GowthamSai@Gowtham-MacBook-Air.local
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 4096]----+
|. .oEo+=o+.      |
|.o o+o.o=        |
|o o o.o. +       |
| =.+ .  =        |
|= *+.   S.       |
|o*.++o .         |
|=.oo.+.          |
| +. +.           |
|.o=+.            |
+----[SHA256]-----+
```

Same way create one more for personal. So, you have 2 ssh keys, work and company. Copy work.pub, work, personal.pub, personal to **~/.ssh/** Directory.

Then create a shell script with the following lines and name it as crev.sh (Company Reverse) with the following content.

```
cp ~/.ssh/work ~/.ssh/id_rsa
cp ~/.ssh/work.pub ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Same way, create one more called prev.sh (Personal Reverse) with the following content.

```
cp ~/.ssh/personal ~/.ssh/id_rsa
cp ~/.ssh/personal.pub ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

in ~/.bashrc add aliases for those scripts like below

```
alias crev="sh ~/.ssh/crev.sh"
alias prev="sh ~/.ssh/prev.sh"
source ~/.bashrc
```

Whenever you wanna use company, just do crev, and if you wanna use personal do prev :-p.

Add those ssh keys to your GitHub accounts. Make sure, you don't have id_rsa generated previously, because those scripts will overwrite id_rsa. If you have already generated id_rsa, use that for one of the accounts. Copy them as personal and skip the generation of personal keys.

Comment: Configure git by running `export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/personal"` rather than switching id_rsa files all the time.  If you forget to set it, you won't use the wrong credentials by accicent.

Answer (score 2):

Although most questions sort of answered the OP, I just had to go through this myself and without even googling I was able to find the quickest and simplest solution. Here's simple steps:

- copy existing `.gitconfg` from your other repo
- paste into your newly added repo
- change values in `.gitconfig` file, such as name, email and username

  `[user]
      name = John
      email = john@email.net
      username = john133`
- add filename to `.gitignore` list, to make sure you don't commit `.gitconfig` file to your work repo

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `git commit --author "Your Name <your@email.com>"` at the moment of doing a commit in a repo where you want to commit as a different user.

Answer (score 1):

Git 2.36 has added the ability to set a user depending on the remote URL:

```
[includeIf "hasconfig:remote.*.url:git@my.enterprise.local*/**"]
    path = .gitconfig-work
[includeIf "hasconfig:remote.*.url:git@github.com*/**"]
    path = .gitconfig-public
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a bash function that handle that. [Here is the Github repo](https://github.com/arount/recursive-gitconfig).

For record:

```
# Look for closest .gitconfig file in parent directories
# This file will be used as main .gitconfig file.
function __recursive_gitconfig_git {
    gitconfig_file=$(__recursive_gitconfig_closest)
    if [ "$gitconfig_file" != '' ]; then
        home="$(dirname $gitconfig_file)/"
        HOME=$home /usr/bin/git "$@"
    else
        /usr/bin/git "$@"
    fi
}

# Look for closest .gitconfig file in parents directories
function __recursive_gitconfig_closest {
    slashes=${PWD//[^\/]/}
    directory="$PWD"
    for (( n=${#slashes}; n>0; --n ))
    do
        test -e "$directory/.gitconfig" && echo "$directory/.gitconfig" && return 
        directory="$directory/.."
    done
}


alias git='__recursive_gitconfig_git'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your ~/.bash_profile to switch between default keys for github.com

```
# Git SSH keys swap
alias work_git="ssh-add -D  && ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa_work"
alias personal_git="ssh-add -D && ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like [Rob W's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220416/can-i-specify-multiple-users-for-myself-in-gitconfig/26170085#26170085), but allowing different a different ssh key, and works with older git versions (which don't have e.g. a core.sshCommand config).

I created the file `~/bin/git_poweruser`, with executable permission, and in the PATH:

```
#!/bin/bash

TMPDIR=$(mktemp -d)
trap 'rm -rf "$TMPDIR"' EXIT

cat > $TMPDIR/ssh << 'EOF'
#!/bin/bash
ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/poweruserprivatekey $@
EOF

chmod +x $TMPDIR/ssh
export GIT_SSH=$TMPDIR/ssh

git -c user.name="Power User name" -c user.email="power@user.email" $@
```

Whenever I want to commit or push something as "Power User", I use `git_poweruser` instead of `git`. It should work on any directory, and does not require changes in `.gitconfig` or `.ssh/config`, at least not in mine.

Answer (score -2):

There can be multiple ways to do this, but I'm achieving this via the below shell function.

```html
function gitprofile() {
    if [[ $1 == "private" ]]; then
        if grep -q "tom@workmail.com" "/Users/tomtaylor/.gitconfig"; then
            echo "Found in gitconfig. No action required."
        else 
            echo "Found in gitconfig1"
            cp /Users/tomtaylor/.gitconfig /Users/tomtaylor/.gitconfig2
            mv /Users/tomtaylor/.gitconfig1 /Users/tomtaylor/.gitconfig
            mv /Users/tomtaylor/.gitconfig2 /Users/tomtaylor/.gitconfig1
        fi
    elif [[ $1 == "public" ]]; then
        if grep -q "tom@gmail.com" "/Users/tomtaylor/.gitconfig"; then
            echo "Found in gitconfig. No action required."
        else 
            echo "Found in gitconfig1"
            cp /Users/tomtaylor/.gitconfig /Users/tomtaylor/.gitconfig2
            mv /Users/tomtaylor/.gitconfig1 /Users/tomtaylor/.gitconfig
            mv /Users/tomtaylor/.gitconfig2 /Users/tomtaylor/.gitconfig1
        fi
}
```

Invoking it like,

gitprofile "public" -> This would switch to profile with `tom@gmail.com` and

gitprofile "private" -> This would switch to `tom@workmail.com`.

Add this function to your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.zshrc based on your current terminal preference. Restart the terminal or just compile the script like

> . ~/.bash_profile

to make the function effective. Hope it helps !

Answer (score -2):

Let's redefine the specs - you just want to be able to use multiple identities with git against different organisations - all you need is 2 oneliners:

```
 # generate a new private public key pair for org1  
 email=me@org1.eu;ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C $email -f $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.$email

 # use org1 auth in THIS shell session - Ctrl + R, type org1 in new one 
 email=me@org1.eu;export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -p 22 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.$email"
```

Why I know that this is by far the most simple solution:

```
  # me using 9 different orgs with separate git auths dynamically
  find $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.*@* | wc -l
  18
```

Comment: You cannot add the same SSH key to mutliple github accounts though