# How to enable multiple usernames for git? ie. Specific project can have specific username

Tags: git, github, git-svn, git-config

I am working with 2 projects in same time. One is for my work and another is my personal project. I'd like to use git as version control software.

I have configured .gitconfig under my my directory as follows.

```
  1 [user]
  2   name = gladder
  3   email = gladder
```

So git can pickup my user settings automatically.
however, I am just wondering that is it possible to get this setting in small scope?

So the project's user settings can override global user settings.

Comment: See also [Can I specify multiple users for myself in .gitconfig?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220416/can-i-specify-multiple-users-for-myself-in-gitconfig).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, all the settings that are in `$HOME/.gitconfig` can be put into `.git/config` inside each repository.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `--file` flag with `git config` (or not as it is the default):

```
git config --file user.name gladder
git config --file user.email gladder
```

which will create/set the value in `project/.git/config` (as araqnid said)

Refer to [git-config](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) for more information.

Comment: Doesn't work on all versions of git `git version 1.8.3.4 (Apple Git-47)` gives error 'key does not contain a section'

Comment: `git config --file .git/config user.name gladder` or `git config --local user.name gladder` both update .git/config for me