# Set git config values for all child folders

Tags: git

I know that it's possible to set per-repo configs which override the user-level config (i.e. `/path/to/my/repo/.gitconfig` overrides `~/.gitconfig`). Is it possible to set git configs which override the user-level settings for all child folders of a given folder? I.e., I have

```
|--topLevelFolder1
|--\
|   ---.gitconfig_override
|--\
|   ---childFolder1
|       \---[...]
|--\
|   ---childFolder2
|       \---[...]
```

And I want the settings defined in `.gitconfig_override` to apply in `childFolder1` and `childFolder2`.

My motivation for this is as follows: I have a work laptop which I also use in my spare time for personal projects. All my work code is nested within a single folder. When I push to work git repos, I need to do so with my work persona - work login instead of name, and work email. When I push to my own personal (github) repos, I want to do so with my real name and personal email.

Other possible solutions I've thought of (and problems):

- Create separate users for "work" and "play", set their user-level settings appropriately, and log in as the appropriate user when I switch context (hassle, plus I could easily forget to switch)
- Create a script that searches for git repos inside "workFolder", and adds/updates their .gitconfig files to hold the appropriate details (if I create a repo and forget to run the script before pushing, I will push as the wrong person)
- "hack" git such that every time it creates a repo, it checks the filepath and, if appropriate, updates the .gitconfig file (complicated, messy, and almost certainly The Wrong Way To Do It - plus, I wouldn't have the first clue how to go about it!)

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220416/can-i-specify-multiple-users-for-myself-in-gitconfig), which only seems to contain solutions for single repos, not multiple. Hopefully someone will see this question who missed that one!

Comment: Will you be working on the same repository as both "work you" and "personal you"? If not, the question you linked to contains the answer I'd give. Your `--global` user settings should contain whichever identity you use more. Each repository that should use the other identity should have `user.name` and `user.email` set accordingly.

Comment: I will never be working in the same repo with two different users - each repo will be either "work" or "home" - but the issue comes from the fact that (for work, at least) I have something like 35 repos, and am adding more regularly. I could add the `user.name` and `user.email` settings in each of the existing repos, and set up a cron script to add them to any newly added repos, but it would be much easier if I could set them in a single place which "filters down" to any repos in child folders.

Comment: @scubbo, please review the answers, as Git has changed, likely making a different answer the correct answer for your question.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up! I just changed the accepted answer.

Answer (score 223, accepted):

As mentioned by [NateEag's edit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24463387/1091015), git's [Conditional Includes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_conditional_includes) are perfect for this. Since that answer's the one for people on git < 2.13, here's one for those who have newer versions.

First, create a new config file somewhere with the settings you want to take effect in the sub-folders - using the original question's folders, let's say it's at `~/topLevelFolder1/.gitconfig_include`

In `~/.gitconfig`, add:

```
[includeIf "gitdir:~/toplevelFolder1/"]
    path = ~/topLevelFolder1/.gitconfig_include
```

Any subfolder of `~/topLevelFolder1` will now include the config in `~/toplevelFolder1/.gitconfig_include` - there isn't a need to manually change the `.git/config` in each subfolder's repo. (This doesn't *override* whatever's in the subfolder config - it just *adds* to it, as "include" implies.)

**Notes:**

- Within `~/.gitconfig` this setting should be located **after** the config you want to override because `includeIf` will be overridden again by any config that comes after it.
- This setting includes the file only if you are **in a repository** under the given path. It's ignored if you're in any non-repository sub-path.
- The trailing forward slash (`/`) in the `gitdir` condition is important.
- `git config --list` is good for testing this. You'll see any overrides below `includeIf` lines in the output. You can also check specific entries with, e.g., `git config --get user.email`
- On **Git for Windows**, specify paths relative to your user directory with `~/` and absolute paths with the Windows-style drive, like `C:/` using forward slashes only. Backslashes and Unix-style mount points like `/c/` don't work. Furthermore, in the `includeIf` part, you must specify the path with the correct case as the comparisons are **case sensitive**.

Comment: The trailing slash (`/`) in the `gitdir` condition is important.

Comment: *This* should be marked as the correct answer for this question. Thanks to the mention of `includeIf` (and a little bit of trial and error), I've now configured one specific folder tree on my work PC in which every Git action identifies me as my personal account and uses my personal SSH key, along with a similar folder for work stuff on my personal PC. Meanwhile the rest of each system uses the appropriate email, name and SSH key on both machines. I only wish I upvote this answer more than once.. (:

Comment: Is the `if` part really necessary?  If the referenced `path` does not exist the entry seems to be ignored.

Comment: If only git just did the logical thing and walked the tree looking for `.git` directories in each parent directory...

Comment: @OliverPearmain The goal isn't to include the file if it exists, but to include the file if you are in a repo under the given path.

Comment: `git config --list` is good for testing this.  you'll see any overrides below `includeif` lines in the output.  you can also check specific entries with, e.g., `git config --get user.email`

Comment: And one more thing. This setting should be located after the config you want to override in ~/.gitconfig. Otherwise, includeIf will be overridden again by the config in ~/.gitconfig.

Comment: It's possible to match directory case insensitive using [`gitdir/i`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-codegitdiricode).

Comment: This should be a standard API config feature without needing to use includeIf. E.g. by traversing the parent paths up and checking .gitconfig and include it.

Answer (score 41):

EDIT: Git 2.13 introduced [conditional includes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_conditional_includes), which are designed to solve this exact problem.

My original answer is preserved below, for history's sake (and users stuck on older versions of git).

====================================

The exact behavior you desire is not supported, based on reading the gitconfig manpage.

However, as of [git 1.7.12](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v1.7.12/Documentation/git-config.txt), Git reads config data from [four different sources](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v1.7.12/Documentation/git-config.txt#L194), two of which are user-specific:

`$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config` and `~/.gitconfig`. Entries in `~/.gitconfig` override entries in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config`.

That means you can store your personal gitconfig at `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config` and put machine-specific overrides in `~/.gitconfig`. Something like

```
[user]
    email = username@example.com
```

in `~/.gitconfig` should cover your email case.

Note that if $XDG_CONFIG_HOME isn't set git will look for `~/.config/git/config`.

This works well for me, since I only ever have two personal repos on work machines (my emacs config and my dotfiles). If you add personal repos to your work machines frequently, this may not be good enough for you.

In that case, custom wrappers around `git init` and `git clone` would be your best bet.

Any binary on your $PATH whose name matches 'git-*' can be called as a git command, so you'd just need a pair of shell scripts that call the original command with all passed args, then copy the correct config file into `.git/config`.

Comment: Some git settings can be controlled by setting environment variables. They override values from config file. A very good utility for setting/un-setting env variables per directory hierarchy is, `direnv`. See my answer below for all the details.

Answer (score 16):

You can use `direnv` command to set environment variables that apply to all child folders. You can be anywhere in that directory hierarchy. If the git setting you are trying to set can be controlled by an environment variable, then you are in luck.

Read the `direnv` basic page http://direnv.net/ to set it up for your shell. For zsh, it was as simple as to stick this line at the bottom of my `.zshrc` and restart the shell.

```
eval "$(direnv hook zsh)"
```

Check if the git setting you want, can be controlled by an environment variable. It seems you want to control `author.email` for a particular directory-tree, which is controlled by environment variable, `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL`. Note, environment variables take precedence over config. A complete list of environment variables git supports are here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables

As, `direnv`'s page specifies, create a file named, `.envrc` at the root of the hierarchy; in your case, `topLevelFolder1`

For example:

```
echo export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=myotheremail@esp.com > .envrc
```

"Allow" the envrc: `direnv allow .` That's it!

Every time you jump into the hierarchy, `direnv` will find the said `.envrc` file and load it.

```
$ cd ~/topLevelFolder1/childFolder1/project_name
direnv: loading ../../../.envrc
direnv: export +GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL

$ echo ${GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL}
myotheremail@esp.com
```

Jump out of the directory structure and `direnv` will unload those variables

```
cd ~
direnv: unloading
```

Answer (score 8):

The `[include]` section in git config (`.git/config`, `~/.gitconfig` ...) is what you are looking for.

```
[include]
    path = /path/to/foo.inc ; include by absolute path
    path = foo ; expand "foo" relative to the current file
    path = ~/foo ; expand "foo" in your $HOME directory
```

See detailed answered question: [Is it possible to include a file in your .gitconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557183/is-it-possible-to-include-a-file-in-your-gitconfig#9733277)

See git-config Documentation: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_includes

**EDIT**

Add in `childFolder1/.git/config` and `childFolder2/.git/config`:

```
[include]
    path = ../.gitconfig_override
```

Comment: OK - so this solves the issue of only defining the `user.name` and `user.email` in one place (in `../.gitconfig_override`), but I don't think it actually answers the original question? If `childFolder1` and `childFolder2` are children of `parentFolder`, I was looking for a way to set config values in `parentFolder` that would filter down to any repos rooted in child folders.

Comment: As [NateEag pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24463387), this was only introduced in Git 2.13. (Git 2.13.0 dates from 9 May 2017.) So, if anyone reading this answer wonders why it doesn't work for them, it might be that they are using an older version of Git.

Comment: NOTE that I recently ran into an issue where these conditional includes didn't appear to be respected. The issue was that git (at least, my install - 2.17.0 on MacOSX) appears to require a trailing slash on directory paths.