# Separate git configurations on parent directories that do not have git config files

Tags: git, github

Say I have two directories in home (~/) that contain git projects: `repo-work` and `repo-personal`. In `repo-work`, I have work related git projects, and in `repo-personal`, I have personal git projects.

I know you can configure git settings locally, globally, or system-wide. Local setting will require not setting global, and setting git configurations for each project, which seems like a hassle.

I can also set global git configurations for either work or personal, and change the local settings for each project of the other repository, but if I forget to do it, my git history gets mixed with my work email account and personal email account, which is a bigger hassle.

Ideally, I would want to have a "directory-specific" settings so that if I set settings for `repo-work`, all projects under that directory will carry that setting, and likewise, for `repo-personal`, the projects under that directory will carry personal git configurations. How can I achieve this?

Comment: [Set git config values for all child folders](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21307793)

Comment: @Basilevs The second link question is very similar to mine, but it seems like there is no clean way to do it. I don't have too many personal repos, so I might just globally set it to work email and set personal repo individually. I will wait for a few more days and close this question.

Comment: @THISUSERNEEDSHELP see my response here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307793/set-git-config-values-for-all-child-folders/37167110#37167110 for exactly the same problem, I had.