# Globally configuring git user email based on path of repository

Tags: git

I have two workspace directories (`W1` & `W2`) and I would like to default the git user email to `email1` for all git repositories under `W1` and `email2` for all git repositories under `W2`.

Is it possible to configure such setting where we can default the git config values for all repo under a certain directory?

This should apply to any newly created git repositories inside `W1` and `W2` as well without additional per-repository configuration.

Comment: Don't think so. What you can do is set global the email you use most often, then set local for each repo when needed

Comment: I believe you can use `includeIf` directives in the global .gitconfig file to include different sub-configuration files depending on criteria, such as the path to the repository. You would then have to set up different such files with different names and email addresses, and include the right one. I don't have any experience with doing it, however, so I don't know if it actually works for you and how you would set it up, but look here for details - https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

Comment: For the time being, I just wrote a bash script that will set a local email for all the repos under W1 and keep a different one at global level. 

But I have to make sure I run this whenever I create

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+different+email

Comment: I'm confident that a.) this is not a duplicate, as it asks a more specific question than the duped question and b.) `includeIf` is a solid lead for this and might solve this, but I've not used it myself so I can't write a reliable answer with this info. @LasseV.Karlsen maybe you want to put that info into an answer? Edit: I've taken the liberty to rephrase and expand the question, please revert this if I missed the original intent.

Comment: @phd please re-read the question, this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Be sure I've done it before pointing to the duplicate. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43884702/7976758) and other answers there give different good solutions. Conditional include is perhaps the best one.

Comment: I agree that the original duplicate isn't a great one (dupes should be based on the question being asked, not the solution), but this _is_ still a dupe. I've added another dupe that's more clearly asking the same thing. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48088291/354577) is likely the most helpful.