# Shell variable expansion in git config

Tags: git, shell

I have a shell variable which points to the directory where all my configuration files are located. Let's assume the variable is created with `export RC=$HOME/rc`. I have a global ignore file in the configuration directory: `~/rc/globalgitignore`.

My Question is, how can I expand the `RC` variable in my `.gitconfig` file?

I already tried the following:

- `excludesfile = $RC/globalgitignore`
- `excludesfile = !$RC/globalgitignore`
- `excludesfile = !echo $RC/globalgitignore`
- `excludesfile = !$(echo $RC/globalgitignore)`

None of these solutions work.

The only way this works if I enter the full path: `excludesfile = ~/rc/globalgitignore`, but then I have to change the path if move my `rc` directory to a different location.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can't. [git-config(1)](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) does not support environment variable expansion, but only limited type conversion and path expansion:

> The type specifier can be either --int or --bool, to make git config ensure that the variable(s) are of the given type and convert the value to the canonical form (simple decimal number for int, a "true" or "false" string for bool), or --path, which does some **path expansion** (see --path below). If **no type specifier** is passed, **no checks or transformations** are performed on the value.

The documentation for `--path` states:

> --path
>
> git-config will **expand leading ~ to the value of $HOME, and ~user to the home directory for the specified user**. This option has no effect when setting the value (but you can use git config bla ~/ from the command line to let your shell do the expansion).

The term "expansion" does not appear in any different context in `git-config(1)`. So how did you even get the idea that it should, given that no such feature is documented anywhere?

In order to expand environment variables you have to pre-process the Git config file yourself, i.e. by creating a template file, and expand variables with a script before copying the file to your `$HOME` directory.

If it's about dotfile management, then do, what all people do: Put them in a directory, and add symlinks to this directory from your `$HOME`.

Comment: Previously I linked all config files from the `rc` directory into my home directory. To omit these links, I created the `RC` variable and the most of my programs uses it.

By the way, the `~` is expanded and when you use git config alias ... then you can use shell commandos and variable expanding.

Comment: @SvenK: Please read `git-config(1)`: The fact that `git-config(1)` expands `~` doesn't "automagically" mean that variable expansion or even shell commands are supported, too. `~` is *specifically handled* by `git-config` if and only if a value is *retrieved with the `--path` type specifier*. This is the *only* kind of expansion supported by `git-config`. I've updated my answer to include the relevant sections from `git-config(1)`

Comment: This is a bit frustrating, as I can't just specify my http[s]?_proxy environment variable for my whole system; I have to for some reason specify it in my gitconfig as well. Pretty annoying for people who don't work from home or a small dev shop, and/or who sit on different networks depending on where they're working.

Comment: @RobertGrant I am pretty sure that Git uses `$http_proxy` and `$https_proxy` from your environment.

Comment: @lunaryorn I didn't observe that behaviour; [this](http://xmodulo.com/2012/04/how-to-use-git-behind-proxy-on-ubuntu.html) guy agrees.

Answer (score 35):

I use bash scripts in my config to enable variable expansion. Just export the variable you need in your .bashrc and use it in the scripts:

In my ~/.bashrc:

```
export TESTVARIABLE="hello"
```

In my ~/.gitconfig:

```
[alias]
    test = !bash -c '"echo \"Value: $TESTVARIABLE\";"'
```

At my bash prompt:

```
bash> git test
    Value: hello
```

---

The other way of doing it, is to add a git config command in your shell's rc. I for instance have in my .bashrc:

```
git config --global user.name "$USER@$HOSTNAME"
```

I have the same configuration on all my machines, and by adding this I can distinguish between commits from different machines. You could do the same and add to your shell rc:

```
export RC="$HOME/rc"
git config --global core.excludesfile "$RC/globalgitignore"
```

Comment: gospes: I tried the first method you suggested for the email field. The resulted email (which I see in the commit information) equal to the string "<!bash -c 'echo -n "$EMAIL>". Ideas?

Comment: @tivoni the example by @gospes only works because it is in the `git alias` group

Answer (score 18):

With Git 2.31 (Q1 2021), you might consider using configuration variable-value pairs via environment variables (and it tweaks the way `GIT_CONFIG_PARAMETERS` encodes variable/value pairs to make it more robust too).

See [commit d8d7715](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d8d77153eafdb0fc334e827976f09e4bdff26b58), [commit b9d147f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b9d147fb150c5e0960bc43ad5f3f843487f816f7), [commit 1ff21c0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1ff21c05ba99ed2d0ade8318e3cb0c1a3f8d4b80), [commit b342ae6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b342ae61b3658ed4c062a27f8e46ea79c38d4197), [commit ce81b1d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ce81b1da230cf04e231ce337c2946c0671ffb303) (12 Jan 2021), and [commit b0812b6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b0812b6ac0776b6e43e8483d5579ffd11d5c5f42) (07 Jan 2021) by [Patrick Steinhardt (`pks-t`)](https://github.com/pks-t).
See [commit f9dbb64](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f9dbb64fadf599c588a39d2251bb3f9a2f7d572a), [commit 13c4495](https://github.com/git/git/commit/13c44953fb0b396d3594b4a712f956ab3a48169e) (12 Jan 2021) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 294e949](https://github.com/git/git/commit/294e949fa2dfd43097b2b5614470a3e43604663d), 25 Jan 2021)</sup>

> ### [`config`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ce81b1da230cf04e231ce337c2946c0671ffb303): add new way to pass config via `--config-env`
>
> <sup>Co-authored-by: Jeff King</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Patrick Steinhardt</sup>

> While it's already possible to pass runtime configuration via [`git -c  <key>=<value>`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ce81b1da230cf04e231ce337c2946c0671ffb303/Documentation/git.txt#L71)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--cltnamegtltvaluegt))</sup>, it may be undesirable to use when the value contains sensitive information.
> E.g.
> if one wants to set `http.extraHeader` to contain an authentication token, doing so via `-c` would trivially leak those credentials via e.g. `ps(1)`, which typically also shows command arguments.
>
> To enable this usecase without leaking credentials, this commit introduces a new switch `--config-env=<key>=<envvar>`.
>
> Instead of directly passing a value for the given key, it instead allows the user to specify the name of an environment variable.
> The value of that variable will then be used as value of the key.

`git` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ce81b1da230cf04e231ce337c2946c0671ffb303/Documentation/git.txt#L16):

> `[--super-prefix=<path>] [--config-env <name>=<envvar>]`

`git` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ce81b1da230cf04e231ce337c2946c0671ffb303/Documentation/git.txt#L83-L104):

> ### `--config-env=<name>=<envvar>`
>
> Like `-c <name>=<value>`, give configuration variable
> '`<name>`' a value, where `<envvar>` is the name of an
> environment variable from which to retrieve the value.
>
> Unlike
> `-c` there is no shortcut for directly setting the value to an
> empty string, instead the environment variable itself must be
> set to the empty string.
>
> It is an error if the `<envvar>` does not exist
> in the environment. `<envvar>` may not contain an equals sign
> to avoid ambiguity with `<name>`s which contain one.
>
> This is useful for cases where you want to pass transitory
> configuration options to git, but are doing so on OS's where
> other processes might be able to read your cmdline
> (e.g. `/proc/self/cmdline`), but not your environ
> (e.g. `/proc/self/environ`).
> That behavior is the default on
> Linux, but may not be on your system.
>
> Note that this might add security for variables such as
> `http.extraHeader` where the sensitive information is part of
> the value, but not e.g. `url.<base>.insteadOf` where the
> sensitive information can be part of the key.

In your case, test it out with:

```
git --config-env=core.excludesfile=RC config core.excludesfile
# or (Git 2.32+ only)
git --config-env core.excludesfile=RC config core.excludesfile
```

The value for `core.excludesfile` should be `$RC` (which should reference the full file path, not just its parent folder though)

---

Note: Before Git 2.32 (Q2 2021), "[`git --config-env var=val cmd`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5f586f55a02b98d7a2a9c770d33e8170ca563e43/Documentation/git.txt#L83)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt---config-envltnamegtltenvvargt))</sup> were *not* accepted (only `--config-env=var=val` was).

See [commit c331551](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c331551ccf9a4c8922ff5d2987eed9e218479000), [commit 9152904](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9152904c1162afaf9ce0305d1988d1450dc80da7) (29 Apr 2021) by [Patrick Steinhardt (`pks-t`)](https://github.com/pks-t).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5f586f5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5f586f55a02b98d7a2a9c770d33e8170ca563e43), 07 May 2021)</sup>

> ### [`git`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c331551ccf9a4c8922ff5d2987eed9e218479000): support separate arg for `--config-env`'s value
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Patrick Steinhardt</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Jeff King</sup>

> While not documented as such, many of the top-level options like `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` support two syntaxes: they accept both an equals sign between option and its value, and they do support option and value as two separate arguments.
> The recently added `--config-env` option only supports the syntax with an equals sign.
>
> Mitigate this inconsistency by accepting both syntaxes and add tests to verify both work.

---

But there is more, still with Git 2.31:

> ### [`config`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d8d77153eafdb0fc334e827976f09e4bdff26b58): allow specifying config entries via envvar pairs
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Patrick Steinhardt</sup>

> While we currently have the `GIT_CONFIG_PARAMETERS` environment variable which can be used to pass runtime configuration data to git processes, it's an internal implementation detail and not supposed to be used by end users.
>
> Next to being for internal use only, this way of passing config entries has a major downside: the config keys need to be parsed as they contain both key and value in a single variable.
> As such, it is left to the user to escape any potentially harmful characters in the value, which is quite hard to do if values are controlled by a third party.
>
> This commit thus adds a new way of adding config entries via the environment which gets rid of this shortcoming.
> If the user passes the `GIT_CONFIG_COUNT=$n` environment variable, Git will parse environment variable pairs `GIT_CONFIG_KEY_$i` and `GIT_CONFIG_VALUE_$i` for each `i` in `[0,n)`.
>
> While the same can be achieved with [`git -c <name>=<value>`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d8d77153eafdb0fc334e827976f09e4bdff26b58/Documentation/git.txt#L71)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--cltnamegtltvaluegt))</sup>, one may wish to not do so for potentially sensitive information.
> E.g.
> if one wants to set `http.extraHeader` to contain an authentication token, doing so via `-c` would trivially leak those credentials via e.g. `ps(1)`, which typically also shows command arguments.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d8d77153eafdb0fc334e827976f09e4bdff26b58/Documentation/git-config.txt#L340-L355):

> ### `GIT_CONFIG_COUNT`
>
> ### `GIT_CONFIG_KEY_<n>`
>
> ### `GIT_CONFIG_VALUE_<n>`
>
> If `GIT_CONFIG_COUNT` is set to a positive number, all environment pairs
> `GIT_CONFIG_KEY_<n>` and `GIT_CONFIG_VALUE_<n>` up to that number will be
> added to the process's runtime configuration.
>
> The config pairs are zero-indexed.
> Any missing key or value is treated as an error.
> An empty `GIT_CONFIG_COUNT` is treated the same as `GIT_CONFIG_COUNT=0`, namely no
> pairs are processed.
> These environment variables will override values
> in configuration files, but will be overridden by any explicit options
> passed via `git -c`.
>
> This is useful for cases where you want to spawn multiple git commands
> with a common configuration but cannot depend on a configuration file,
> for example when writing scripts.

For example:

```sh
    GIT_CONFIG_COUNT=2 \
        GIT_CONFIG_KEY_0="pair.one" GIT_CONFIG_VALUE_0="foo" \
        GIT_CONFIG_KEY_1="pair.two" GIT_CONFIG_VALUE_1="bar" \
        git config --get-regexp "pair.*"
```

will print:

```
pair.one foo
pair.two bar
```