# Git config file local variables

Tags: git, git-alias

I have a set of aliases for different type of logs, like:

```
lg = log --graph --pretty=format:'%C(cyan)%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(red)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
unreleased = !git --no-pager log --graph --pretty=format:'%C(cyan)%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(red)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative release..master
```

There are many type of log aliases, but most of them share the same format. How can I define a local variable with the content of the common parts?

Ideally, I would like to avoid using an environment variable for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262010/shell-variable-expansion-in-git-config), [git-config](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) doesn’t support expansion of variables. What you can do, however, is define an alias with the common parts:

```
lg = log --graph --pretty=format:'%C(cyan)%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(red)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
```

Then define further aliases as shell commands that use the common alias:

```
unreleased = !git --no-pager lg release..master
```

---

Incidentally, specifying `--date=relative` has no effect, since `%cr` in your log format is by definition a relative date. This also means that `--date=short`, for example, would have no effect. You’ll need to use `%cd` instead if you want any of your other aliases to be able to change the date format.