# git config include: path with variable

Tags: git, git-config

Git config allows to include files like:

```
[include]
    path = /path/to/file
```

My question is: can I use environment variable to specify the file name? Like `path = /etc/git/$MYVAR/gitconfig`.

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables are not resolved when Git is reading a config file.

The only one which [might be expanded is ~](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-codegitdircode):

> If the pattern starts with `~/`, `~` will be substituted with the content of the environment variable `HOME`.

Generating the config you need ([through `.bashrc` for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21574502/6309)) is one workaround.

Answer (score 0):

No that's not possible. Git doesn't evaluate environmental variables when processing config.

There is conditional include directive `[includeIf]` that allows to include different configs based on where repository is (`gitdir:`) or which branch is checked out (`onbranch:`). For example following snippet:

```
[includeIf "gitdir:~/repos/work"]
    path = ~/repos/work/.gitconfig
```

in your `.gitconfig` will make Git only include `~/repos/work/.gitconfig` for repos under `~/repos/work` - e.g. `~/repos/work/proj1` but not `~/repos/fun/project2`. See more info on https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_includes

This is available since Git version 2.13