# How to set different properties for multiple git repositories

Tags: git

I point to 2 different git repositories

```
git@github.com:blah/foo.git
git@mycompany.com:random/bar.git
```

I push two different SSH public key(s) into github.com and mycompany.com
When I push code to the respective git repositories, I need to set the user.name and user.email properties for git. How do I set different names/emails for different repositories.

Comment: is your question about how to actually do the pushes (in title) or how to set different properties for multiple repos (in question)? if the latter, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220416/can-i-specify-multiple-users-for-myself-in-gitconfig

Comment: If I have to set it individually to each repo, where am I supposed to run this command. Is it from the checked out location?

Comment: I would assume so since they mention the .git folder, which is project-specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$> git config user.mail "mail@a.c"
$> git config user.name o
$> cat .git/config
[user]
    mail = mail@a.c
    name = o
```

https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git