# Is there such a thing as git "profile manager"?

Tags: git

Background: As a freelance consultant, I often contribute to different Git repositories with different identities (typically email addresses issued by various clients). On top of that, I've got my personal GitHub profile. And I use the same laptop for all development work.

Whenever I check out a new repository, I have to manually edit the user configuration on my hard drive to ensure my commits will be marked with the correct author information.

I'm looking for something like a "profile manager" that will automagically do this for me, maybe based on some environment settings. Is anyone aware of this kind of tool?

Comment: How much time do you actually spend running those two commands?

Comment: There is an argument to be made for forcing you to make sure that you have the right information in the repo

Comment: You could setup environment variables by sourcing different shell files.... and with different environment variables, git might use different values for name and email then. Check https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables `Committing`.

Comment: 1) "*Whenever I check out a new repository*" Presumably you mean when you *clone* a new repository? 2) I'm not aware of such a thing, but how would it know which identity to use for which clone?

Comment: If you're willing to organize your repos into subfolders such that each author/email is used in a specific subfolder, then you can use conditions in your global .gitconfig file to automatically select the proper "profile" based solely on what repo you are in. See [this question for details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57275547/184546). Note that the question is actually asking how to fix the duplicates while having a default profile, but my answer indicates that you probably can just not worry about that, since the last entry "wins".

Comment: I'm using what @TTT suggested: one folder per organization and I configure git username once per folder. Then cloning as subfolders.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43654115/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/44036640/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+multiple+emails