# I accidentally pushed code to my repo from another git user

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-commit

So here's what happened.

- I had a public repo on github.
- I cloned it to a unix system at my college.
- I made changes using VS Code.
- I used Vs code's inbuilt git management tab to push and sync changes.
- It asked me to log into GitHub with my account using the browser, and so i did it, with 2fa.
- The code was pushed successfully.
- Several days and commits later in the contributions, i see an unknown name, on investigation i realise that it was on the same day as when i pushed from my college system.
- This probably happened cause that user logged into the local git on the system.

Is there anything I can do to fix this ?

Comment: What you see on github is the *author* of the commit, which is completely separate from *the user account you use to connect to github*. In order to "fix" the situation, you need to change the author (and possibly the committer) of said commit.

Comment: shameless plug: another response I wrote to explain the difference between author and github credentials: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75680759/86072