# How do I check my github settings or who I'm signed in as on my current project through the terminal?

Tags: git, github

My friend set up my github for me and cloned a project onto my desktop. I want to see what is my profile name on the Github account he gave me. Is there a command to do that?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can see the current configurations, including username, with `git config -l`.

You'll want to look for `user.name`, `user.email`, and `github.user`.

You can unset configurations using `--unset`, like `git config user.name --unset`.

You can also reset configurations using `git config user.name "Your Name"`.

Comment: I see credential.helper=osxkeychain when I use git config -l. how do I go on from here to see my username?

Comment: I followed this but didn't find github.com anywhere

Comment: I accessed with a token, but I can't see any information here

Answer (score 35):

To see which user is accessing github via terminal you could try SSH

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

You get the following response

```
Hi Keshavdulal! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

I have multiple ssh keys setup for different projects and it helps to know the current user.

Comment: That's helpful and how do you change the user?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51997218/3556531 @Houman This should help.

Answer (score 20):

```
git config -l | grep user.name
```

This will only output `username` in the terminal. Similarly, for `email` type:

```
git config -l | grep user.email
```

Note: This will only work on mac. For windows, refer to the comments.

Comment: it says: 'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
what's wrong?

Comment: on a Windows system you can use `findstr` instead of `grep`

Answer (score 9):

you can check your project git config using:

```sh
git config -l
```

Answer (score 4):

To add to Briana's response; use '--global' to modify the .gitconfig file and permanently change your user name. Without '--global' you would only be changing your user name for that session.

i.e.

```
git config --global user.name "your.user.name"
```

would save your user name so that you login as "your.user.name" when git starts up.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `git remote -v` to list the remote repositories linked to your local clone.

You'll see GitHub repository URL which may contain your GitHub user name in the middle.

Note that your GitHub user name might be different than your local username and email, which are not validated by any means (you can put whatever you want in those configuration settings).

Comment: This doesn't work on any repo that isn't yours (e.g. <user>/<repo>)

Answer (score 0):

I usually use:

```
git config -l | grep user
```

This shows your user.name and user.email

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?