# Can't change git config's user.name, gets reset immediately

Tags: git, git-config

If I do:

```sh
 git config --global user.name "My New Name"
```

It works, for a short while. If I do this:

```sh
cat ~/.gitconfig
```

I can see the proper value in the `user.name` property.

However, as soon as I open a new terminal window or do a git commit, the old name gets reset.

I'm using ssh. Is there some cache mechanism?

(Note this is not about the GitHub username, but rather about the author name for every commit)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change my Git username in terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844806/how-to-change-my-git-username-in-terminal)

Comment: Make sure you are also updating the repo url. `git remote set-url origin https://username@bitbucket.org/repository.git`

Comment: No, this is not the problem. I'm not trying to update my GitHub user name, rather my author name.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it works for a short while? Does it work when you do `git commit`?

Comment: @unrealsoul007 I explained in the question body.

"as soon as I open a new terminal window or do a git commit, the old name gets reset"

Comment: It sounds like something in your shell startup scripts are changing it.

Comment: What shell are you using? Does auto-complete work with git?

Comment: Does the `~/.gitconfig` file actually *change?* Does `git config --get user.name` produce a different answer from `git config --global --get user.name`? If `~/.gitconfig` changes, figure out what's changing it, and fix that. If not, but the local and global settings don't match, fix *that*. Also, be sure that you're using `~/.gitconfig` and not `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config`.

Comment: @kelvin bash. No, auto-complete doesn't work with git.

Comment: @torek Yes, `~/.gitconfig` actually *changes*. No, adding the `--global` flag doesn't change the output of `git config --get user.name`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a shell script that was overriding the global `~/.gitconfig`. Specifically, this `.extra` file from Mathias Bynens' [dotfiles](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles).

[See this GitHub issue for more details](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/issues/408).

Answer (score 4):

The [FILES section of the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES) shows sources of configuration values.

> If not set explicitly with `--file`, there are four [or five] files where `git config` will search for configuration options:
>
> 1. `$(prefix)/etc/gitconfig`
>    System-wide configuration file.
> 2. `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config`
>    Second user-specific configuration file. If `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is not set or empty, `$HOME/.config/git/config` will be used. Any single-valued variable set in this file will be overwritten by whatever is in `~/.gitconfig.` It is a good idea not to create this file if you sometimes use older versions of Git, as support for this file was added fairly recently.
> 3. `~/.gitconfig`
>    User-specific configuration file. Also called "global" configuration file.
> 4. `$GIT_DIR/config`
>    Repository specific configuration file.
> 5. `$GIT_DIR/config.worktree`
>    This is optional and is only searched when `extensions.worktreeConfig` is present in `$GIT_DIR/config`.

As to their precedence

> The files are read in the order given above, with last value found taking precedence over values read earlier. When multiple values are taken then all values of a key from all files will be used.

In the case where you modify a repository’s config with `git config` or `git config --local` (which will modify `$GIT_DIR/config`, so either `.git/config` for a repo with a work tree or `config` in a bare repo), and changes through `git config --global` (stored in `~/.gitconfig`) will be invisible inside that repository.

For a quick sanity check, run two commands.

```
git config --global user.name
git config --local  user.name
```