# macOS BigSur keeps resetting the gitconfig located at ~/.gitconfig

Tags: git, macos, git-config

After certain time git reports an error to identify myself and the gitconfig file is set to

```
[user]
    name = =
    email = =
```

Comment: Are you using any Git frontend, customized hooks, or shell configuration, or Git integration in your tooling that might be causing this?  Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57998652/cant-change-git-configs-user-name-gets-reset-immediately) look like it might be correct?

Answer (score 4):

Turns out for me it was Atom editor resetting my git config. Atom won't let me configure it for some reason so I have to stop using it for now.

Comment: I've been having the same issue (in Catalina) - and use Atom also. I've found that the Github Package in Atom is the culprit - you can configure it (click the "Git" button bottom right of the screen), although I've yet to see if this fixes it. If not, you can disable the Github Package (in settings -> packages).