# When pushing into github it is getting pushed from some other user

Tags: git, github

I am pushing into repositories from my laptop using Git Bash which is Riturajrs but it is showing that it was pushed from an account I was previously logged into. I also tried reinstalling git bash but problem persisted. Please help. Apparently the problem must be in web browser which is changing my name after being pushed

Comment: When you say "it is showing that it was pushed from an account I was previously logged into" where do you see this?

Comment: In commits section. Once I have pushed it from my system, in repository it shows NAPS pushed whereas my id is Riturajrs

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844806/how-to-change-my-git-username-in-terminal

Comment: You don't "log in" to Git: you just use it. There are no saved log-in credentials. There *is* a `user.name` and `user.email` setting; Git uses those to set the corresponding strings in new commits. When you run `git push`, Git uses either https or ssh, and *those* have *authentication* (not "logging in") and those are very different. So you need to decide which things to fix: `user.name` etc as shown by `git log`, or authentication to GitHub. GitHub authentication will depend on whether you're using https or ssh.

Answer (score 2):

Your git config has your old settings in it.

To set your global username/email configuration:

```
Open the command line.
Set your username: git config --global user.name "FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME"
Set your email address: git config --global user.email "MY_NAME@example.com"
```

(source: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/configure-your-dvcs-username-for-commits/)