# How to override git config global at Azure DevOps local config?

Tags: git, github, azure-devops

I have one github account and 3 azure devops accounts.

With my personal github profile, I'm using my personal GPG key for auth my commits and tags and this config was made global, but for those azure devops accounts, I don't need to auth commits/tags with GPG.

I've tried to change local git config for each project, but It failed and still using GPG key at those azure accounts.

By the way, I'm using Visual Studio GUI to commit at those Azure DevOps repos.

It's there anyway to still use GPG for global(github personal account) and change my local azure repos git config to not use gpg auth?

I've tried those solutions, but without success.

1. [Command line and git config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51997218/20591161) based on this other stackoverflow post [project overrides global and global overrides system](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16682441/20591161)
2. I've tried those:

```
git config commit.gpgsign false
git config tag.gpgsign false
```

But It still using global config.

3. And I have tried to change .git/config file for each azure devops project and add those lines:

```
[commit]
    gpgsign = false
[tag]
    gpgsign = false
```

Thanks for your time! Happy coding ppl!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's definitely weird that just setting commit.gpgsign didn't do the trick. You should try setting [push.gpgsign](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pushgpgSign) to false, or try directly passing [--no-gpg-sign](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---no-gpg-sign) when committing and the equivalent [--no-signed](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---no-signed) when pushing.

If the later doesn't work then there might just be something wrong with your git installation, at that point a reinstallation might be your best bet.

Comment: Yep, it solved! I don't know why, but Visual Studio git GUI conflicts with my git windows install. Just reinstalled and worked at visual studio. Thanks @javier-flores