# when I git push always asked for username & password

Tags: github, git-push

I recently changed my username on github. Whenever I try to git push changes on old repos I am always asked for my username and password.

**NOTE THAT BEFORE I CHANGED PASSWORD I WASN'T ASKED FOR USERNAME AND PASSWORD**

How can I get rid of this prompt? and git push without being asked for username and password.

[its asking for username](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Exjo.png)

I dont want to constantly putting username and password.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change my Git username in terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844806/how-to-change-my-git-username-in-terminal)

Answer (score -1):

Update your credentials

git config --global user.name "YourNewUsername"
git config --global user.email "YourNewEmail"

Comment: When doing so, which directory should I be in?

Comment: The "--global" part of that answer means that you can do it anywhere.  Including in a directory that isn't tracked by Git.

Comment: i used git config --list and everything is up to date. either way I have done so but I am still experiencing the same thing. I am using WSL Ubuntu 20... on Windows

Comment: The [Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#user-name) says that `user.name` is typically a personal name and has nothing to do with authentication.