# Configuring Git to have different settings for Github and Visual Studio

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2013

I want to be able to have two Git configurations; one for Github and one for Visual Studio Online through VS2013. I want to have all my Github commits displaying one email address (public) and all my Visual Studio online having a different email (private). I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220416/can-i-specify-multiple-users-for-myself-in-gitconfig) however it doesn't quite answer the issue. Do I have to do what it suggests on all repositories? Or shall I configure my global settings to the one I will use the most and then apply this setting to the other ones?