# Name and email set in Git's per-user configuration file, however Git is still using the default generated name and email

Tags: git, config

The title says it, but I will explain it more thoroughly:

I have configured my user's name and email as recommended using the commands:

```
git config --global user.name
git config --global user.email
```

I can verify that this is set by doing `git config --global --list` and I get the following output:

```
core.user=Joshua Guerra
core.email=joshua@allianceconsults.net
core.editor=nano
push.default=simple
```

I can also verify it by doing `cat ~/.gitconfig`, where the output is:

```
# This is Git's per-user configuration file.
[core]
# Please adapt and uncomment the following lines:
user = Joshua Guerra
email = joshua@allianceconsults.net
[core]
    editor = nano
[push]
    default = simple
```

So, I have verified that it is set properly. However I still get a message when I commit that says:

```
Your name and email address were configured automatically based on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly:

    git config --global user.name "Your Name"
    git config --global user.email you@example.com
```

And before you say, this only sets the values for future commits, understand that I understand that. Also, I have set this and repeatedly gotten the message that the values were NOT set even AFTER I set them and verified each time that they were set when I go to commit something.

I'm at a loss for why my system keeps giving me this message. If you need more info about what version and system I am on, I am happy to provide it upon request.

Comment: I think this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43654115/9402438) to how setup per-project `gitconfig`s may be related here.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `name` and `email` settings should appear in the `[user]` section of `~/.gitconfig`.  They are not set correctly.  Your `~/.gitconfig` could have resulted from running the commands:

```
git config --global core.user "Joshua Guerra"
git config --global core.email joshua@allianceconsults.net
```

The commands that should have been run are:

```
git config --global user.name "Joshua Guerra"
git config --global user.email joshua@allianceconsults.net
```

To verify that the settings are correct, run `git config --global --list` and check the output for:

```
...
user.name=Joshua Guerra
user.email=joshua@allianceconsults.net
...
```

Comment: I see that I did not read what I did as carefully as I thought. sigh. Thanks for your help