# Change GIT account of Visual Studio Team Explorer

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, azure-devops, git-credential-manager

I am having a very weird situation when cloning a Git repository from our company private server. The repository is not anonymous (it requires authentication), but when cloning, VS didn't ask any username and password and automatically use an old authentication of old employee. Is there a way to remove the saved username and password and make Visual Studio to prompt them when cloning?

Answer (score 213, accepted):

Look in the Windows Credential manager and remove/update your credentials there:

[image]

Comment: Thank you I have never entered this place of my computer. TIL!

Comment: Under Windows 10 use `rundll32.exe keymgr.dll,KRShowKeyMgr` to open this regardless of the language in the OS.

Comment: works for my gitlab account and the gitlab visual studio 2017 plugin. thanks

Comment: I don't have any credentials in my credentials manager! Visual Studio does not prompt me for credentials and tells me it cannot access the repository

Comment: As mentioned in my comment above, I didn't have any credentials to delete on my credentials manager. What did the trick in my case was deleting the .gitconfig file, altogether (check @saastn answer)

Comment: @AlexanderSchmidt thank you so much! since i don't have administrative permissions on my system i could finally open the credential manager via your "code"

Answer (score 22):

In my case just removing credentials from Windows Credential didn't fix it. I first removed all git and azure related accounts from Windows Credential, then removed accounts from VS>Files>Account Settings, and then VS asked me new credentials and connected to the project. But my commits were still made with the old account! Finally I found out that it was the git config:

```
C:\Users\[USER NAME]\.gitconfig
```

I deleted the whole user section in that file which looks like this:

```
[user]
    name = [OLD ACCOUNT NAME]
    email = [OLD ACCOUNT EMAIL]
```

On next commit VS asked me git account information and done.

If you want to work with different accounts for different projects on same machine, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4220416/2093077).

Comment: once the other answer worked, but this time, this was the only thing that worked. Thanks saastn

Answer (score 7):

I am using VS 2017 and this is how I updated my Password for TFS, using Git repository.

1. From the Menu: Team -> manage Connection
2. Click on *Manage Connection* Link -> Connect to Project

[image]

It will then open window to connect to your project, here you can update your password.

Answer (score 0):

If you make changes to the connection, you must connect again.
in visual studio menu(view->teamExplor)
in Team Explorer ->manageConnection
you can add newConnection or apply the changes