# Can't make git bash re-ask password (windows, no admin rights)

Tags: windows, git, credentials

I'm using Git Bash in Windows 10. When I tried to clone repository using HTTPS, it asked me password once and then failed with "authentification failed" each time. Seems like it saved wrong password, but I can't make git ask my password again.

credential.helper=manager is system-level setting, so I can't edit it since I have no admin rights (also I can't open credentials manager).

This didn't work:

git config --global credential.helper wincred

git config --global credential.helper store

Comment: Have you tried clearing the password in the Windows Credential Store? https://stackoverflow.com/a/31052428/736079

Comment: @jessehouwing Thank you so much, this worked! (I've tried some wrong "credentials thing" components of control panel before, but now I got the exact name in my system language.)

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate based on your comment. Good to hear you're out of your pickle.