# How to specify more than one email address in 'git config --user.email'

Tags: linux, git, commit

I have specified two email addresses in my GitHub account. Now I want to have the same in the command line so my commits are assigned to both email addresses. How is this possible?

Comment: Have you tired a semicolon ;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220416/can-i-specify-multiple-users-for-myself-in-gitconfig

Answer (score 0):

You can edit `~/.gitconfig` file and add both of your email separated by `;`

```
1. sudo vi ~/.gitconfig
2. name = UserName
   email = email1@example.com;email2@example.com
3. Save the file.
```

Comment: Your sample is separated by colon. Should it be colon or semicolon?

Comment: I think this won't work because in the commit log in github, it does not show my name under my commits.