# Git: Set local user.name and user.email different for each repo

Tags: git, github

I'm currently working on 2 projects, which expect that I configure my local username and email with different data when I push to them. For that I'm updating my config all the time like:

`git config --local user.email "namelastname@domain.example"`

Since they are different repositories, is there a way I could define an local email for each repository?

Maybe in the `.gitconfig`?

Comment: repo = all branches, all versions, etc.  So when you say "since there are different branches...can I define email for each repo?"  this doesn't make sense.  What do you want: different email settings for each repo? or different email for each branch?

Comment: For others coming here, check out [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43654115/2084315) to this other question that is similar, and the answer is based on folder structure + a separate .gitconfig for all repos under that directory

Answer (score 662, accepted):

For just one repo, go into to the relevant repo DIR and:

```
git config user.name "Your Name Here"
git config user.email your@email.example
```

For (global) default email (which is configured in your ~/.gitconfig):

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name Here"
git config --global user.email your@email.example
```

You can check your Git settings with:
`git config user.name && git config user.email`

If you are in a specific repo which you setup a new user/config for (different to global) then it should show that local config, otherwise it will show your global config.

Comment: Just in case it helps anyone else you can check what your current settings are by omitting the last part e.g. git config user.email

Comment: This doesn’t work for me: if I set a different local name/email for a repository, then the push to origin still takes the credentials from the global settings — which is exactly what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: @ChrisOwens I edited the answer to add your really useful comment. Cheers.

Comment: @Jens what helped for me was running `git commit --amend --reset-author --no-edit` this reset the current commit to use the local config (after running the above commands).

Answer (score 21):

You can confirm that by printing on the terminal:

1. Global user:`git config --global user.name`
2. Local user: `git config user.name`

Answer (score 21):

...or just edit the `.git\config` file and add these three lines somewhere:

```
[user]
    name = YourName
    email = your@email.com
```

Comment: is this in _each/per_ repo ?

Comment: @Pure.Krome yes and no. You can do both. Add this to each repo or only once to the .gitconfig under your user profile folder (if you're on Windows; I don't know the location for Linux).

Answer (score 9):

It can be achieved with below commands,

```
    git config --local credential.helper ""
    git push origin master
```

It asks for username and password for current repo.

Comment: After add 
`git config user.email <myemail>` 
then above command. Confirm do the trick!

Answer (score 7):

I generally tend to keep diff name/email for my company project and personal project(on github)

Run below command in the git repo where you need to specify the user/email

```
git config user.name <user-name>
git config user.email <user-email>
```

Answer (score 2):

One trick that has been reliably working for me is to set both a global config `credential.username` option as well as a local one. They will ask for a password for authentication. This works even for Git Credential Manager say on a Mac. For more information, please see: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git. So you can cache like at least two different passwords for two different GitHub accounts.