# Why my Repository uploaded from different account from Git Bash

Tags: git, github, commit, git-bash

I've logged in the Git Bash. But I want to push a commit from different account. Both accounts are working on same repository. When I tried to commit from the second account that time it asks for username and password. Although I put the username & Password but it committed by the first account which was logged in the git bash. How can I able to commit by the second one's account.

Comment: it might be using the account used in git config.

Comment: how can i make it to use other account? Is there are any convenient way to that?

Comment: try: `$ git config --global user.name "John Doe"
$ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commits are associated with the user defined in the git config.

It is not clear in the question, but I assume that the username / password prompt happens when you `push` to a remote repository, these are used to verify that you ave permission to push, not to identify the author of the changes.

In order to support two different users committing from the same accounts, you may store two git clones in two separate directories.

Configure users per directory this way, this only needs to be done once:

```
git config user.name "Your Name Here"
git config user.email your@email.com
```

Related question: [Git: Set local user.name and user.email different for each repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42167345/git-set-local-user-name-and-user-email-different-for-each-repo).