# Does anyone know why my Git commits have the double icon associated with them?

Tags: github

I don't understand why I have 2 grey'd github icons:

[image: commits]

Comment: Can you share the link to the repo? Do you see a user when you go over the grey symbol?

Comment: Sorry its a private repo.  When I hover over the symbols, they separate but provide no other feedback.  I noticed one other thing.  The entries said "Karlton authored and Karlton committed" as if they are separate accounts.  It is true I have two accounts, one for public GitHub and one for our enterprise GitHub.  I have no idea how the accounts got their wires crossed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that the commits are not linked to your GitHub user. There is a [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/committing-changes-to-your-project/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user#commits-are-not-linked-to-any-user) from GitHub:

> If your commits are not linked to any user, the commit author's name will not be rendered as a link to a user profile.
>
> To check the email address used for those commits and connect commits to your account, take the following steps:
>
> 1. Navigate to the commit by clicking the commit message link.
>    [image]
> 2. To read a message about why the commit is not linked, hover over the blue  to the right of the username.
>
> [image]
>
> **Unrecognized author (with email address)** If you see this message with an email address, it means the address has not been added to your account settings. To link your commits, add the email address to your GitHub email settings. If your email address has a Gravatar associated with it, the Gravatar will be displayed next to your username, rather than the default gray Octocat.
>
> **Unrecognized author (no email address)** If you see this message without an email address, it means you used a generic email address that can't be added to your email settings. You will need to set your commit email address in Git, then add the new address to your GitHub email settings to link your future commits. Old commits will not be linked.
>
> **Invalid email** This means the email address in your local Git configuration settings is either blank or not formatted as an email address. You will need to set your commit email address in Git, then add the new address to your GitHub email settings to link your future commits. Old commits will not be linked.

You can [link your GitHub user to git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42167345/git-set-local-user-name-and-user-email-different-for-each-repo) by setting `user.name` and `user.email`. The mail must be identical. However, this only works for future commits. For past commits, you can do the following:

```sh
git reset --soft HEAD
git config --global user.email "your_email@host.com"
git commit -c ORIG_HEAD
```