# Push to Github with a GitHub user, not some name added

Tags: git

I am using GitHub at work and each time I push some commits to our remote depository the user is some unknown user with Name set within Git:
git config --global user.name "John Smith"

Then when I look at commits on a repo it appears as "John Smith" which is some unknown GitHub user.

[image]

Each time I push from my local computer the John Smith "account" is the owner of commit. The other one is my GitHub account and it is only when I do some branch merge on GitHub.

Expected behaviour: my GitHub user should be the owner of my commits as well...

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64105777/10951752) can also be helpful if you want to change your commits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution which was pretty easy. The only thing that needs to be done is to set your git email locally to the same email address as it is in your GitHub account.

To check your GitHub email go to settings --> emails