# setting git config for multiple project

Tags: git, github, git-config

I'm working on multiple projects and those projects are connected to different github account. my main project's config was set using `git config --global user.name "firstusername"` and the second project used `git config user.name "secondusername"`. but when I tried connecting the second one to github using `git push -u origin main`, it says `Permission to secondusername/secondusername.github.io.git denied to firstusername`.

when I open gitbash on the second project folder and run `git config user.name` it gives `secondusername`, but when I run `git config --list --show-origin` the credentials says like this

```
...
file:C:/Users/home/.gitconfig   user.name=firstusername
file:C:/Users/home/.gitconfig   user.email=firstemail@gmail.com
...
```

but when I checked the `secondproject/.git/config` file the contents looks like this

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[user]
    name = secondusername
    email = secondemail@gmail.com
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/secondusername/secondusername.github.io.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

what am I doing wrong??

Comment: This is odd, because the [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42167345/3216427) (not a duplicate question!) suggest that what you did should have worked.

Comment: `git config --list --show-origin` will list all the entries : add ` | grep user` afterwards and you will see both the global and the local entry being mentioned

Comment: hmm.. is my question not thorough enough or something? what's with the downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`user.name` and `user.email` are only used to write the name of the author and/or committer when you create commits on your local repo (`git commit`, `git merge`, `git rebase`, ...).

The credentials to connect to a remote service, on the other hand, should be somehow provided through the remote's url.

---

Try changing the remote url of your second repo to : `https://seconduser@github.com/seconduser/...`

Another way is to access github through ssh, and set up your local workstation (its `ssh_config` in particular) to be able to easily target both accounts :

[Multiple GitHub Accounts & SSH Config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17158985/86072)

Comment: I'm sorry, but are you sure the syntax is correct? because yours look like a bitbucket url instead of github.. if I were to try yours then it would look like this, right? `git remote set-url https://seconduser@github.com/seconduser/seconduser.github.io.git` don't you think it's a bit weird? also, when I run `git remote get-url origin` it already says `https://github/seconduser/seconduser.github.io.git`

Comment: @dapidmini : you need to somehow log in as `seconduser` on github. The `https://user@somehost.com/` syntax is a rather standard way to provide a username together with an http/https url, and understood by the satndard browsers and command line tools (e.g : `wget` or `curl`), and AFAIK it should work with github. I personnally use ssh and ssh keys, and use a setup as described in the link to be able to select which account to use.