# Git push with specific credentials

Tags: git, github, authorization

I'm trying to push to my remote on GitHub. Every time, however, I try to do `git push`, git responds with:

```
remote: Permission to wojciechsura/easysass.git denied to <user name>.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/wojciechsura/easysass.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I'm using that  in another repo, but I *don't* want to use it on this one. I have no clue, where that other username is cached.

How to force git ask me for credentials?

Comment: Try `~/.netrc` and see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-on-github

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220416/can-i-specify-multiple-users-for-myself-in-gitconfig

Comment: See this answer :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git

Comment: Follow the instructions [on this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39608906/216074) to remove your credentials from the credential store.