# How can I config two different git repo with different credentials in one system?

Tags: git, github

**Local Repository-1**

I have been working on application for my organization whose git repository cloned at C drive folder.
 I have set global configurations, and I have been able to perform commit, push, pull operations. This is private repository of my organization with unique user name, password and url. Everything working fine this repository.

**Problem**

**Local Repository-2**
  Now, I want to create local repository of my own github project (different from first one) on the same system, but on different location. This repository have different configurations than other repository on the same system. So my concern is, how can I maintain repository specific configurations(user name, password, urls) on the same client system.

Comment: What do you mean, exactly?  Are you using a different public key for this repository, or do you want to set a different name/email combination for this repository?

Comment: I have explained my problem in detail. Thanks for the reading my problem.

Comment: The answer from Amit is fine if you are okay with setting up every repo separately. There is an alternate method that will set up credentials for every repo nested in a given folder.

See [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43654115/6501141).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You have the below 2 options, Based on your preferred way (ssh or password) based access to git account:-

**SSH based access**:- create 2 ssh key-pairs one for your company git account and one for your own git account. you need to add **public ssh keys** on both the git accounts by following [this](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/) article.

**Password based access** :- In this case you don't need to do anything, you just need to give the **username** and **password** on git push etc.

**Important:-** Now you need to add the git configs (git username, email etc) for your system, git has option to set these at **global** and **local** leval. I would recommend setting the **user.email and user.name** setting globally according to your organization, to avoid commits to your company repo which has your private git username and email.

For example below git command will show the global setting of git :-

```
git config --global --list
user.name=<firstname.lastname>
user.email=<company mail address>
```

And to set the git username and password in your private git repo, use below command, inside your repository

```
git config --local user.name "amit"
git config --local user.email "amit@mail.com"
```

You can confirm, that your own private repo does not have, your company `username` and `password` by running `git config --edit` command or `git config --local --list`.

Comment: glad to know that @SandeepKharat

Comment: there is no need to have a global config is there? can't you just have local configs

Comment: in your last code snippet you don't actually set the password

Comment: No need for 2 ssh key pairs.

Comment: Same comment as @TobiasCudnik - no need for multiple SSH keys. Just upload the public key to every remote you need to connect to. The public key does not allow someone that has it to act as you - only to authenticate that it is you connecting to them. There is no security issue with uploading the same public key multiple places. The security issue is if you move your private key. Do not copy it to a USB or move it to another PC. Create a separate SSH key pair for every device you use and upload the separate public key to each account that needs it...

Comment: In case anyone else runs into this: you will need two keys if you need to add them both to the same provider. For example I have two gitlab accounts (one work, one personal) and want to access both from one computer. Trying to use the same key for both, it gives me an error that the fingerprint has already been taken.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon this question and wanted to drop a new development in this area by github CLI team.

`gh` (Github CLI) has recently added feature to support multiple account.

You can now easily switch between accounts using `gh auth switch` command.

More details here: https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_switch