# Git profile switcher for VSCode(preferably)

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I keep forgetting to switch accounts and make commits with the wrong git profile.

I use **VSCode** to push commits and i was wondering if there **is any extension that can show or change the current Git email/profile ?**
Or some way to make it prompt me to enter the email before each commit?

If not, do you know any other free tiny software that can do this?

[GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/) has it, but it is the only feature i really use, and i won't pay just for that.

[image]

Comment: The normal way to do this would be to set `user.name` and `user.email` in your repository's Git settings (`.git/config` inside your repository). On the CLI you can use [the `git config` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) for that; I suspect that Visual Studio Code provides an UI to do the same. Is there some reason that this wouldn't work for you?

Comment: I never set specific users for each repo. Didn't even know about it. I just switch between profiles `git config --global user.email "personal@domain.com"` or `git config --global user.email "work@domain.com"`

Comment: I _strongly_ recommend setting per-repository `user` values. Almost anything that can be set globally with `git config --global` can be set locally (per-repository) without `--global`.

Comment: Take a look at this answer from [Tomáš Janoušek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3407728/tom%c3%a1%c5%a1-janou%c5%a1ek):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220416/can-i-specify-multiple-users-for-myself-in-gitconfig/43654115#43654115

I used it for my own purposes and it works ok as long as you have your projects in separate folders for the different profiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you just set the username for the repository itself, and not globally, using:

```
git config user.email name@domain.com
```

If for some reason you don't want to do this, because you want to commit something with email A and something else with email B for example, perhaps you could use an alias that switches the profile and does the commit? Something like this:

```
git config alias.c "-c user.email=name@domain.com commit -m"
```

`c` being my typical alias for commit. So you'd use this like this:

```
git c "my commit message"
```

You could create two aliases like this one to switch quickly between two different emails.

Comment: The alias is nice way to keep things short, but i will still forget to use it. But as you said i should probably stop messing with the global `user.email` and add it in each repo.

Comment: I'm not crazy about the alias suggestion here. IMO the right solution is to set repository level `user.name` and `user.email` values, as in your first option and my comment above.

Comment: I'm not either, but as mentioned in my answer, he may, for whatever reason, want to commit quickly with two different users on a regular basis.