# GitLab identity management

Tags: git, gitlab

I am working with two different GitLab instances simultaneously. I’d like to use two different emails for my commits for each of them. Is that possible? How does GitLab determine my identity? Is it solely based on the global mail I set using git?

Thanks for sharing your workflows

Comment: It uses the git config. The local config is kept in the .git folder in the root folder of your project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I specify multiple users for myself in .gitconfig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220416/can-i-specify-multiple-users-for-myself-in-gitconfig)

Comment: It's all about your `.gitconfig` file. I made a piece of bash that could help you to handle that: https://github.com/arount/recursive-gitconfig