# Easily set a git project with specific user settings

Tags: git

I'm looking for a way to work with multiple users of mine with GIT.
I want to be able to switch easily user-specific configurations, that I need at the moment.

Something like a group flag for a bunch of settings in `.gitconfig`.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4220416/2350423) question, but couldn't find satisfaction in the suggested answers:

1. The [selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4220493/2350423) suggests to use the `git config` command in the repo, but it's error prune and not so comfortable to do it every time.
2. The [answer about the folder conditional include](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43654115/2350423) is very nice, but it will work only if there's a specific rule for the folder matching those configurations, which there isn't, since it's not necessarily under the same path.

Any other possible solution I'm missing?

What I thought about, in case there isn't a builtin/known way, is to write a script that will get a parameter of the current environment name I want and will run some `git config` commands locally on the current repo folder.

Comment: Do you want to specify which group you are using each time?

Comment: What's wrong with 2? You only need to do it once per project.

Comment: @JosephK.Strauss Might be something like different name, email, CRLF replacement, mergetool etc.

Comment: @jingx I clarified that point, the thing is that it's not necessarily under the same folder path, so I can't use the `gitdir` option

Comment: But surely each project has a fixed root path, so you just need to add 2 lines for each project. Also it supports glob: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_includes

Comment: Of course, but then I'll need to update the `.gitconfig` each time. But you gave me an idea with the blob - do you know in which part the configuration update takes place? on `git init` I guess? If so, maybe I can create a file name `config.personal` / `config.work` etc. and set the blob to match it