# How to use different global emails for github and bitbucket?

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket

I been using bitbucket for a long time of period and never use github alongside with it, Recently I wanted to use github for particular reason. For github I wanted to setup global email that is different from bitbucket global email. is it possible to setup to two different global email address for both accounts and how do I do that?

Comment: Are you asking how to set up your gitconfig?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I specify multiple users for myself in .gitconfig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220416/can-i-specify-multiple-users-for-myself-in-gitconfig)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+global+email

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set up two different emails at a `global` level, but yes you can have it at a repository level.

From the command line, change into the repository directory and set your email address as:

```
git config user.email "MY_NAME@example.com"
```

Verify your configuration by displaying your configuration file:

```
cat .git/config
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you could achieve that by cloning in 2 different directories.
One called `bitbucket` and one `github`.

And then using `.gitconfig` cnditional include to load either the github config or the bitbucket one.

See [.gitconfig include documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_includes)