# Working with two different Github Accounts

Tags: git, github

I have a personal and Work Github Accounts.

By default, git user.email is set to my personal email address. (`git config user.email`)

Is there a way if I clone repos from Work github account - it will use work email address automatically? Or what is right approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I specify multiple users for myself in .gitconfig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220416/can-i-specify-multiple-users-for-myself-in-gitconfig)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+two+different+emails

Answer (score 1):

There are several levels of ranges for [`git config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config),

1. `--global`, writes to `~/.gitconfig`
2. `--system`, writes to `${prefix}/etc/gitconfig`
3. `--local`, default, writes to project `.git/config`
4. `--worktree`, writes to project `.git/config.wroktree`, similar to `--local`

You can use the project wide `--local` config files to [override the `--global` value](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES), that is, when you setup a project with work account, immediately `git config` to add a project wide `user.name` and `user.email`.

Comment: Is there a better approach by using multiple accounts with `~/.gitconfig`? And maybe with the help of `git alias`?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you configure your git with `git config user.name` & `git config user.email`whenever you need it. Otherwise, if you can work with your two accounts on the same project, you can add your second account as a contributor.