# Config for folder with repos

Tags: git

I don't like `git config --global` because I use more accounts.

I also don't like setting config every I wanna clone some repo.

I am looking for something like this:

```
folder01/
    ..there is one clonned repo..
folderO2/
    ..there is two clonned repo..

git config <folder> user.email ...
```

I need repos in folder inherit the config from parent folder.

Both folder aren't repos, just folder.

I clone repos into some folder and sometimes I remove some repo.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I specify multiple users for myself in .gitconfig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220416/can-i-specify-multiple-users-for-myself-in-gitconfig)

Comment: @phd not really

Comment: @dan1st In what way not?

Comment: @phd He also wants git configs for directory trees.

Comment: @dan1st Conditional includes described at the linked Q perfectly solve that. And in a much better way than regularly run a script tat could easily be forgotten.

Comment: @phd But it doesn't allow configs for multiple directories.

Comment: @dan1st It does. There could be many includes with different conditions. There could be recursive includes.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want one config for your system, you could just configure it with `git config --system` (as admin/root).

If you want to use the same config for multiple users (but not all users), you can create this config and a link to that config in the home directory of each user.

There is no possibility do that directly(at least I don't know any).

However, there are a few interresting things:

- The command `git config` has a `--file option`. With this, you can configure seperate config files.
- You can set the config file for you `git config --local include.path "<config file>"`.

With that, you can create a new config file for your directory and when you create a directory, you can just set the config file of a directory using `git config --local include.path "<config file>"`.

You can also automate that by writing a script, that automatically scannes all directories for e.g. a config file and executes `git config --local include.path "<config file>"` if it finds any files.

That script could look like that(if you use linux/bash):

```
#!/bin/bash

git init

initDir="$PWD"

while [ "$PWD" != "/" -a ! -f "./.gitconfig"  ] ; do
        cd ..
done
if [[ -f "./.gitconfig" ]]; then
        configFile="$PWD/.gitconfig"
        cd $initDir
        git config --local include.path "$configFile"
fi
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the part "*I also don't like setting config every I wanna clone some repo.*"

Comment: @phd The script can be easily adapted. It is possible to e.g. greate a `gitclone` script that does the same thing with `git clone`.