# Aliasing (or another method) a command to set git ENV variables before committing on remote shell?

Tags: bash, git

I have a remote shell that me and a few others work on. I'd like to set it up so that I can run something like `gitcole ; git commit -m"example"`.

Where gitcole sets the relevant env variables for just that command, namely:

```
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME is the human-readable name in the “author” field.

GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL is the email for the “author” field.

GIT_COMMITTER_NAME sets the human name for the “committer” field.

GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL is the email address for the “committer” field.
```

I'm not very familiar with bash. How would I tackle this?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what is the problem with it? What steps have you taken to become more familiar with the tool you're trying to use?

Comment: I haven't tried much because I don't want to misconfigure .bashrc on a remote machine that I don't own.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26170085/7976758

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got this to work like so:

In my `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    cacm = -c user.name='colemars' -c user.email='MY_EMAIL' commit
```

Then you can use it like `git cacm -m"commit message"`

And repeat for other users.

Way simpler than I initially tried making it.