# How to disable GPG signing per repo

Tags: git, gpg-signature

I currently have GPG signing setup on my computer it works fine.  This is required to commit to the repo of the company i work for using my company email address.

How ever I also contribute to a number of open source repos under my own personal git account using my personal email address.

The problem is that when ever i commit anything it wants to commit as my work account and not as my personal account and it pops up with the GPG signing window asking for my password.

I managed to get it to stop using this.

```
git -c commit.gpgsign=false commit
```

How ever i am looking for a permanent way of turning GPG sign off for different repos.  I have already set them up to use my email in those repos but i haven't been able to figure out how to get the GPG to stop for those repos.

Comment: I think what you are actually looking for is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43654115/10155936), different configs for personal and company work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> How to disable GPG signing per repo

For setting the configuration per repository you can run the command below in each local repository you want GPG signing to be disabled ,

```
git config --local commit.gpgsign false
```

or

```
git config commit.gpgsign false
```

From git [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt---local),

> **--local**
>
> For writing options: write to the repository .git/config file. **This is the default behavior**.