# Two differents accounts for one project GITLAB

Tags: git, gitlab, commit, git-commit

I don't speak English very well, but I will try to explain my problem in the best way.

I have two accounts for different gitlab servers, one for my work and another personal, for example:

`User: personal-user → Email: personal@gmail.com → Server: gitlab.com`

`User: work-user → Email: user@work.com → Server: work.gitlab.com`

But I only have one project, when I commit, gitbash asks me for an user and an email, but they are different for each server.

If I make the `commit` with a specific user and when I review the `commits` on the gitlab server it shows me that the user who made the commit is missing.

please check the next image:

[image]

**How could I manage the project and upload it to the different servers in the best way?**

The idea is that when I do a push gitlab can register the commits for each specific user that corresponds to each server

Comment: Are you working on the same project repository with the two remote repositories (personal and work)?

Comment: Yes, I'm working in one project but I want to backup on two repositories (personal, work) @GoodDeeds

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43654115/5987698) will help?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't get completely some aspects of your question.
But some time ago I faced similar problem - managing multiple GitHub accounts.
I've written this small article describing how to organize them on your machine: https://boiko.ru/posts/multiple-github-accounts/