# Can I set a username/email for all directories under some directory?

Tags: git

So I have my global 'user.email' as "myPersonalEmail@gmail.com". But I also have a folder that holds my work projects, organized like:

```
repos/
  workRepos/
     databaseMonitor/
     salesWebapp/
  sudokuSolver/
  someCoolGame/
```

I know I can set the local user.email on each sub-repo in `workRepos/` to "rollie@companyname.com", but I'd rather set it directly inside `workRepos/` so all projects underneath resolve my email to the company email, and I don't accidently submit something with the wrong identity.

I am hesitant to initialize a git repo in `workRepos/`, as some tools will show me the contents of *that* repo, instead of the one I'm working on. It seems like something git would have, to allow like a `.git.settings` file that is used if found anyone above the repo, to override the global settings.

From the SO recommended similar questions, I see that some config can be supplied in the global git config file, which would work, but I don't like complicating that, plus everything would break if I moved my repos to a new location, so it's not ideal, but probably what I'd do.

Is this the case? Any suggestions on doing what I want? Or am I stuck specifying this on a per-repo basis like some sort of Neanderthal?

Comment: similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43654115/6908282

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible to do this using different `.gitconfig` files. My home directory looks like this:

```sh
~
-> .gitconfig
-> .gitconfig.personal
-> .gitconfig.work
-> /personal
-> /work
```

The contents of `.gitconfig`:

```sh
# default to work config
[include]
  path = ~/.gitconfig.work

# when working on personal projects
[includeIf "gitdir:**/personal/**/.git"]
  path = ~/.gitconfig.personal

[gpg]
    program = gpg
[commit]
    gpgSign = true
```

The contents of `.gitconfig.work`:

```sh
[user]
  name = Blair Nangle
  email = blair@work.com
  signingkey = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

The contents of `.gitconfig.personal`:

```sh
[user]
  name = Blair Nangle
  email = blair@personal.com
  signingkey = YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
```

Now, when I'm working on any Git projects that reside under `~/personal`, my personal Git config will be used.

You can test your config by running `git config user.email` from `~/work/a-project` and `~/personal/another-project`.

Comment: Yeah this is the solution I had too. It's a bit finicky - like trying to `includeIf ~/repos/` and then subsequently `includeIf ~/repos/work/` seems to silently not work - maybe it doesn't like setting the value twice and won't allow overwrite? In any case, yeah thinking the above is the best currently available, though I still like my proposed approach better than this.

Comment: Do you need to define `includeIf` twice? Isn't a default and then one overridden path sufficient? (This isn't a particularly elegant solution, granted.)

Comment: The thinking was "This is where my repos go, under that is work repos. If I'm working with code elsewhere, I should be forced to make a decision about my identity"

Comment: Fair. I think the problem probably then lies in `workrepos` being a subdir of `repos`.