# Xcode failed to push files because "Communication with the service was interrupted"

Tags: xcode, git, github, xcode14

I've been trying to push my project from xcode to github but it keeps giving me an error message that the communication with the service was interrupted. Previous commits and pushed have worked but its broken now. I've already tried restarting my computer and Xcode but it still doesn't work. I'm trying to push about 4-5 commits here with some video files. I've seen a similar question asked here but the solution didn't really help.

[image]

I get this error message after a long time of of loading whenever I try to push. Commit works but pushing does not.

Comment: I'd suggest using a dedicated git client (such as Fork or SourceTree) or the command line git interface, since Xcode's built in git client is quite buggy and limited in its features.

Comment: do i download the git client or access it through terminal? And after that, do i just use the git commands like git commit/ git push to do it because the changes have already been stashed and commited, just have an issue with pushing it

Comment: You can just use the built-in git client of macOS from the terminal. You don't need to commit again, since your changes are already committed to git. You simply need to navigate to your project folder in terminal, then push from there.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, this is a [known issue in Xcode](https://roncsak.medium.com/i-couldnt-add-swiftui-packages-to-xcode-6f748822ed6a). It occurs when your **global** `.gitconfig` file has a configuration that Xcode does not understand. For example, if you [use `includeIf` statements to distinguish git profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220416/can-i-specify-multiple-users-for-myself-in-gitconfig/43654115#43654115).

I had the same problem (using Xcode 13). To work around it, I removed the `includeIf` statements, and [set up **local** `.gitconfig` files to distinguish git profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220416/can-i-specify-multiple-users-for-myself-in-gitconfig/).