# Git: Is there any sane setup for work and personal identities on the same computer?

Tags: git, git-config

I work remotely, and I have two main folders on my PC – one for personal projects and another for work projects. I obviously need to keep the identities separate for repositories residing *deep down* in those folders. Git doesn't [natively](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#SCOPES) support this use case. Is there any known good practice to address this scenario?

Note I'm not talking about remotes; I'm talking about my identity as a commit author (i.e. name and, most importantly, e-mail address).

**TL;DR**: Use [`[includeIf]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220416/can-i-specify-multiple-users-for-myself-in-gitconfig/43654115#43654115), it solves this.

**LE:** Currently reviewing and testing the recommended solution (it looks promising). Will come back with a resolution.

**LE2**: I just can't get [`[includeIf]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220416/can-i-specify-multiple-users-for-myself-in-gitconfig/43654115#43654115) to work for now. Will retry tomorrow and will come back with a resolution. I assume I'm doing something wrong.

**LE3**: I'm testing this on Windows, using [GitExtensions](http://gitextensions.github.io/). This doesn't work when I commit using the GitExtensions GUI. But if I execute `git config --show-origin --get user.email` from the GitExtensions shell, it does report the work e-mail address correctly (my default is personal, `[includeIf]` is work). I'm starting to think this is related to GitExtensions somehow, even though it's just supposed to be a thin GUI layer above git. Kinda confusing.

**LE4**: GitExtensions is buggy in that it *displays* the wrong committer in the commit dialog, but the actual git commit properly honors the `[includeIf]` directive. Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43654115/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+multiple+email

Comment: For me the best solution is to keep work and personal repos in 2 different parent directories and use conditional include to have a specific identity in all the repos of one of the parent folder like done in https://stackoverflow.com/a/43654115/717372