# Having Trouble Switching Github accounts on terminal

Tags: git, ssh, github, ssh-keys

It's been a while since I pushed anything to GitHub.  I had initially set up my account on my computer, and everything worked great.  Then I changed my account to a client's account (so I could push code to their private repository).

It's been a while and now I am changing back to my old account, and I am having trouble.  I generated a new rsa_key and pretty much followed the [instructions here](http://help.github.com/mac-set-up-git/) to a T.

However, when I type: `ssh -T git@github.com` I get:

Hi oldincorrectusername! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

I can't push to my repos either, because this old client username isn't authorized.  I've doublechecked my ssh keys both on my computer and on my account setting on GitHub.

I've also set my global account variables:

```
git config --global user.name "Firstname Lastname"
git config --global user.email "your_email@youremail.com"
git config --global github.user username
git config --global github.token 0123456789yourf0123456789token
```

And still it is giving me the old username.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Comment: Each repo may have local git settings, did you read those? `git config --local --list` whilst in a repo.

Comment: Does your origin urls contain the user information? (`url = user@github.com/user/project.git`) Use `git remote show -vv origin` to find out

Comment: @knittl - How would that even matter if `ssh -T git@github.com` gives the old username

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The problem is that your local *ssh* is still offering your “old” SSH key to GitHub. This often comes up when you have one GitHub-recognized key (i.e. your “old” key) loaded in an *ssh-agent* but want to use a different GitHub-recognized key (i.e. your “new” key).

*ssh* offers keys in this order:

1. specified keys that have been loaded into the agent
2. other keys that have been loaded into the agent
3. specified keys that have not been loaded into the agent

By “specified keys” I mean those keys specified by the `-i` command line option or the `IdentityFile` configuration option (which can be given through `~/.ssh/config` or the `-o` command line option).

If your “old” key is loaded into the agent, but your “new” key is not, then *ssh* will always offer your “old” key (from the first or second categories) before your “new” key (only ever in the last category since it is not loaded), even when you specify your “new” key with `-i`/`IdentitiesOnly`.

---

You can check which keys are loaded in your *ssh-agent* with `ssh-add -l`. If your “old” key is listed, then you can fix the problem by unloading it from your agent (be sure to also unload any other GitHub-recognized keys, except perhaps your “new” key):

```
ssh-add -d ~/.ssh/old_key_file
```

If you are using Mac OS X, the system may be automatically loading your “old” key if you checked “Remember password in my keychain” when prompted for the password at one point; you can disable this automatic loading by deleting the Keychain entry for the key with the command
`/usr/bin/ssh-add -K -d ~/.ssh/old_key_file`. Other systems may do something similar, but the commands to tell them to “stop that” will be different.

---

Instead of unloading the “old” key from your agent, you can set the `IdentitiesOnly` configuration option to `yes`, to tell *ssh* to skip the second category of keys (non-specified agent-loaded keys). Your `~/.ssh/config` might include a section like this:

```
Host github.com
    User           git
    IdentityFile   ~/.ssh/id_rsa # wherever your "new" key lives
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

This way, it will not matter whether any other GitHub-recognized keys are loaded into your agent; *ssh* will always offer only your “new” key.

If you anticipate needing to access the repositories of both GitHub accounts and you do not want to have to edit the configuration file whenever you want to switch between GitHub accounts, then you might setup your `~/.ssh/config` like this:

```
Host clientname.github.com
    HostName      github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/client_id_rsa  # or wherever your "old" client key lives

Host github.com
    IdentityFile   ~/.ssh/id_rsa        # or wherever your "new" key lives

Host github.com *.github.com
    User           git
    Hostname       github.com
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Then use URLs like `github.com:GitHubAccount/repository` for your repositories and URLs like `clientname.github.com:GitHubAccount/repository` for your client’s repositories (you can put the `git@` prefix back in if you like, but it is not necessary since the above entries set the `User` configuration variable).

Comment: Thank you for an incredibly complete answer. I learned a lot in reading it. I ended up using the IdentitiesOnly method you described.