# Github Permission Denied

Tags: github, permission-denied, multiple-users

Banging my head on this github multiple user thing and hoping I can get some help!

I just added a new email to my existing github account, changed my git configs locally to the right name and email, and added the ssh key to github but when I try to push my new project I created it says permission denied. I have the right repo set up for my origin too.

What's confusing me is when I do `ssh -T git@github.com` it says you've successfully authenticated with my other user...

I know I'm missing something so if you see it please let me know!

Thanks

Comment: Found My Problem Here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548158/having-trouble-switching-github-accounts-on-terminal

Was using old stored ssh key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A full ssh url will work:

```
ssh://git@github.com/User/repo.git
```

But here, you might be using an scp-like syntax, like the [question you mention](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7548158/6309):

```
github.com:User/repo.git
```

You risk using an entry "github.com" entry in a `$HOME/.ssh/config` file, which can then specify explicitly a different private key, as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14423667/6309).

```
Host github.com
   Hostname github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myprivatekey
```