# overwrite current github account associated on a server/repo

Tags: git, github

our server currently use an account of an employee which has just resigned and due to that his account is disabled.

`git config --list`
when i run this command it seems it is displaying all of my information which i just set.

but when i pull/push/fetch etc i get the error

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

and when i run this command `ssh -T git@github.com` it is saying:

`Hi resigned employee! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

what should i change for the repo to use my account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ssh, you need to change the public/private key stored in the server account `~/.ssh` folder in order to use your own public key, and not the ssh key of the "resigned employee".
You need to [generate your own set of ssh keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys).
See [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996) for an example.

Check also if that old key is still offered by ssh-agent (that happens if your private key is passphrase protected): see "[Having Trouble Switching Github accounts on terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7550935/6309)" for more.

Comment: co worker cloned a new copy of repo before i tried your method's. but thanks for the pointers