# Logout and login as another user git bash

Tags: git, version-control

I want to logout from Git bash and login it again as another user .

I have googled but can't find any solution.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You don't have to "logout" or "login": regarding git, who you are is determined by:

```
git config user.name
git config user.email
```

Change those two settings while being in a repo, if you are someone else, when it comes to creating commits.

If you want to change it in your local machine for all repos, add --global like

```
git config --global user.name [your username]
```

---

As suggested by the Deepak swain's answer, you can also change credentials in Windows using the Credentials Manager by typing in the console:

```
rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr
```

As Kartik Ranpise answer's and Stuart Axon's contribution

But Credentials are about `git remote -v`, that is with the user account you will use to push to the [upstream repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309).

- for an HTTPS url, you can simply [specify a new user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22356933/6309)
- for ssh, you would need a [`~/.ssh/config` file referring to multiple private ssh keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15551505/6309) (also [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7550935/6309)). In which case, the Credential Manager would not be involved.

Answer (score 29):

use

```
git config --global user.name [Your User name]

git config --global user.email [Your Email]
```

Comment: Thanks for the command to actually change the setting. Not just check them.

Answer (score 23):

For Windows User: 
Follow Instructions: Control Panel >> User Account >> Credential Manager >> Windows Credential >> Generic Credential 
You can change git credential click modify>>provide uname and password 
Or you can remove git credential. next time when you'll push repo it'll ask you for credential.

Comment: `rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr` will open this from the commandline.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using GitHub CLI you can use `gh auth status` to see the current logged account. `gh auth login` and `gh auth logout` allow login and logout as required.