# Can't sync local git master to existing git hub remote repository

Tags: git, bash, authentication, github, multiple-accounts

I currently have a local git master for a school project that has been uploaded to a github account. I then used github online to transfer my repository to a second github account (for professional reasons, I'm re-branding). That worked well.

The new problem was having two GitHub remote repositories. I removed the first GitHub repository and then added the second, but when I tried

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

I was quickly informed:

```
remote: Permission to *****/****.git denied to myOldUserAccount.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/*****/****.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I feel like this is a login problem with GitHub. How do I authorize my second account to act in the affairs of my first? All my searches only returned [Logout and login as another user git bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740734/logout-and-login-as-another-user-git-bash) which wasn't helpful in this instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can't access to your remote repository, please check your `.git/config` file
and check

```
url = https://github.com/username/yourrepositoryname.git
```

is correct ? 
if url is correct but still you get error, then you can add password with your url.

```
url = https://username:password@github.com/username/yourrepositoryname.git
```

i think it's worked.

Comment: Thank-you, that was helpful!