# Git Bash still pushing with previous username

Tags: github, push, git-bash

So, I am attempting to push a repository to Github using Git bash. The thing is, it still thinks that I am using a username that I was previously using. However, I changed this username and I checked to be sure with the following commands:

```
git config user.name
"CorrectName"
git config user.email
"CorrectEmail@correctdomain"
git config --global user.name
"CorrectName
git config --global user.email
"CorrectEmail@correctdomain"
```

However, Github is still using my previous user name to push the repo. This is evident by the command to push:

```
git push origin master
remote: Permission to CorrectName/CorrectRepo.git denied to PreviousUsername
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/CorrectName/CorrectRepo/': The requested URL
returned error: 403
```

What can I do in order to successfully push my repo?

Comment: I am still having this issue a day later. Does anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it to work. Someone helped me and advised me to run a
`git config --local credential.helper ""` command in my project directory and also a `git config --global --unset credential.helper` command. It seems like the credentials were still being stored somehow, but git asked for a username and password before pushing after unsetting the credential helper and the push was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing you remote and re additing it.

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin <your origin url>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your user settings:

Name:

```
$ git config --global --unset user.name
```

Email:

```
$ git config --global --unset user.email
```

or all your global settings:

```
$ git config --global --unset-all
```

Then [set your username](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/)  in git.

To check who you are:

```
$ git config --list
```

Comment: @kevin29 You can visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740734/logout-and-login-as-another-user-git-bash) to see how to log out from git and then login again, I think that's the easy way to do it!

Comment: That is what I already tried in the original post. Any other ideas?

Comment: If you remove completely from your computer your git configuration and reconfigure again, it should always work.