# git public key for more repositories

Tags: git, github

I'm having following problem.

I have 2 projects and I use github. 1st project went smooth, I created a public key, entered passphrase and pushed into github. no problem.

2nd project, I created another public key and when I want to push to the 2nd repository, it keeps asking for the passphrase for the 1st code /.ssh/id_rsa. but id_rsa holds my public key for 1st project. so of course, when I enter passphrase it wont work because it will try to push into 1st repo instead of 2nd.

how can I create a public key and tell git that I want to push to another repo?

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare your different ssh keys in a `~/.ssh/config` file, as I explained in "[How to manage multiple ssh keys in the ~/.ssh directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23751734/6309)"

I would recommend not using the default name for the keys, but rather:

```
~/.ssh/proj1
~/.ssh/proj1.pub
~/.ssh/proj2
~/.ssh/proj2.pub
```

And then have a `~/.ssh/config` like:

```
Host ghproj1
    User           git
    Hostname       github.com
    IdentityFile   ~/.ssh/proj1
    IdentitiesOnly yes
Host ghproj2
    User           git
    Hostname       github.com
    IdentityFile   ~/.ssh/proj2
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

You need to change the origin url in both repos:

```
cd /path/to/cloned/proj1
git remote set-url origin ghproj1:yourProject1

cd /path/to/cloned/proj2
git remote set-url origin ghproj1:yourProject2
```

See more at:

- "[How to change git ssh user for a remote push temporarily?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15551505/6309)"
- "[Having Trouble Switching Github accounts on terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7550935/6309)"

An url like `ghproj1:yourProject1` is an ssh one which will explicitly use the key you specified in `~/.ssh/config` for the `ghproj1` entry.

In the OP's case ([answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24141880/6309)), the correct url would be:

```
~/.ssh/id_recaprojekt
```

Note: **you need to specify the path to the private key (private, not public, not `.pub`)**

```
cd /path/to/cloned/plastickychirurg
git remote set-url origin plastickychirurg:michalfeher/plastickychirurg.git

cd /path/to/cloned/recaprojekt
git remote set-url origin recaprojekt:michalfeher/recaprojekt.git
```

Note that I have added "Hostname" in the Host entries.

The all idea of those entries in the ~/.ssh/config file is to not (repeat *not*) put `git` or `github.com` in the url (it is done for you by the items associated to each entries):

So:

```
 git@github.com:michalfeher/recaprojekt.git
```

is the same as:

```
 recaprojekt:michalfeher/recaprojekt.git
```

Except the second url will use the ssh key

Comment: Thank you for you answer @VonC! But apparently I am doing something wrong. I will give you my examples.