# Multiple ssh keys for multiple accounts on bitbucket/github, not working

Tags: git, ssh

I'm having trouble trying to get this work even though there's ton of questions on this topic. Either I'm missing something or they're not what I want.

I have two accounts on github - `account1` and `account2` with their respective repositories

```
git@bitbucket.org:account1/repo.git
git@bitbucket.org:account2/repo.git
```

On my PC I've created 2 separate SSH keys for each one `account1_id_rsa` and `account1_id_rsa`

They both individually work when I name them just `id_rsa` and by default it all works. But I want to be able to keep they keys named `account1_id_rsa` and `account1_id_rsa` and still be able to push/pull without having to rename each one depending on which repo I wanna work on at the moment.

After reading many QAs on the topic, I still can't figure out what to put in my `.ssh\config`. So far I've tried

```
Host           bitbucket
HostName       bitbucket.org
IdentityFile   ~/.ssh/account2_id_rsa
User           account2
```

```
Host           bitbucket
HostName       bitbucket.org
IdentityFile   ~/.ssh/account1_id_rsa
User           account1
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here

http://kevinpelgrims.com/blog/2012/07/19/setting-up-multiple-github-accounts-on-windows

```
Host           account1.bitbucket
HostName       bitbucket.org
IdentityFile   ~/.ssh/account1_id_rsa
```

```
Host           account2.bitbucket
HostName       bitbucket.org
IdentityFile   ~/.ssh/account2_id_rsa
```

And most importantly, I needed to have the following git URLs

```
git@account1.bitbucket.org:repo.git
git@account2.bitbucket.org:repo.git
```

Comment: Also in https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996, http://stackoverflow.com/a/24135308/6309 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/23751734/6309